# HTTP GET in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, http-get

What is the best way to issue a http get in VB.net? I want to get the result of a request like http://api.hostip.info/?ip=68.180.206.184

Answer (score 80, accepted):

In VB.NET:

```
Dim webClient As New System.Net.WebClient
Dim result As String = webClient.DownloadString("http://api.hostip.info/?ip=68.180.206.184")
```

In C#:

```
System.Net.WebClient webClient = new System.Net.WebClient();
string result = webClient.DownloadString("http://api.hostip.info/?ip=68.180.206.184");
```

Comment: `Dim webClient As System.Net.WebClient = New System.Net.WebClient()` can be abbreviated to `Dim webClient As New System.Net.WebClient`
can't it?

Comment: @MattLyons Yes, it can. One could also omit `As String` from `Dim result As String = ...`, but I'll just leave that here for now.

Comment: What if the webpage requires a username and password?

Comment: @Matt Use [`HttpWebRequest`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/92588/11963) and set the [`Credentials`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.credentials.aspx) property to a new instance of [`NetworkCredential`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.net.networkcredential.aspx).

Answer (score 26):

You can use the HttpWebRequest class to perform a request and retrieve a response from a given URL. You'll use it like:

```
Try
    Dim fr As System.Net.HttpWebRequest
    Dim targetURI As New Uri("http://whatever.you.want.to.get/file.html")         

    fr = DirectCast(HttpWebRequest.Create(targetURI), System.Net.HttpWebRequest)
    If (fr.GetResponse().ContentLength > 0) Then
        Dim str As New System.IO.StreamReader(fr.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
        Response.Write(str.ReadToEnd())
        str.Close(); 
    End If   
Catch ex As System.Net.WebException
   'Error in accessing the resource, handle it
End Try
```

HttpWebRequest is detailed at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx

A second option is to use the WebClient class, this provides an easier to use interface for downloading web resources but is not as flexible as HttpWebRequest:

```
Sub Main()
    'Address of URL
    Dim URL As String = http://whatever.com
    ' Get HTML data
    Dim client As WebClient = New WebClient()
    Dim data As Stream = client.OpenRead(URL)
    Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(data)
    Dim str As String = ""
    str = reader.ReadLine()
    Do While str.Length > 0
        Console.WriteLine(str)
        str = reader.ReadLine()
    Loop
End Sub
```

More info on the webclient can be found at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx

Comment: Drop the semi-colon from str.Close(); in first example then all good.

Comment: WebClient is a quick solution, but the HttpWebRequest is more powerful. In a project I needed to get images metadata from remote resources: I avoided to download the images into the fs, and I used the ResponseStream insted.

Comment: `Response.Write(str.ReadToEnd())` assumes she is using asp.net.

Comment: @Wolfwyrd will this work with `https` or does one have to use additional api.

Comment: @marshalcraft - should work fine for https see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/560804/how-do-i-use-webrequest-to-access-an-ssl-encrypted-site-using-https for pointers if it's not working for you

Answer (score 5):

Use the [WebRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webrequest) class

This is to get an image:

```
Try
    Dim _WebRequest As System.Net.WebRequest = Nothing
    _WebRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(http://api.hostip.info/?ip=68.180.206.184)
Catch ex As Exception
    Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Exit Sub
End Try

Try
    _NormalImage = Image.FromStream(_WebRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
Catch ex As Exception
    Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Exit Sub
End Try
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is `System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile` or `DownloadString`.

Answer (score 1):

You should try the [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) class.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.CreateDefault(RequestUrl);
request.Method = "GET";

WebResponse response;
try { response = request.GetResponse(); }
catch (WebException exc) { response = exc.Response; }

if (response == null)
    throw new HttpException((int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "The requested url could not be found.");

using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())) {
    string requestedText = reader.ReadToEnd();

    // do what you want with requestedText
}
```

Sorry about the C#, I know you asked for VB, but I didn't have time to convert.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Function getLoginresponce(ByVal email As String, ByVal password As String) As String
    Dim requestUrl As String = "your api"
    Dim request As HttpWebRequest = TryCast(WebRequest.Create(requestUrl), HttpWebRequest)
    Dim response As HttpWebResponse = TryCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
    Dim dataStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
    Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)
    Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
    Dim result = responseFromServer
    reader.Close()
    response.Close()
    Return result
End Function
```

Comment: i just make a function and call it