# WebClient call works in WinXP but not on Win7

Tags: c#, .net, windows-7, bluesnap

The following call returns a result in WinXP but not on Win7:

```
 using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                var result = client.DownloadString("https://secure.plimus.com/jsp/validateKey.jsp");
            }
```

I get "System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out" exception

What is it that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: In what way does it not work? Do you get an exception?

Comment: I get "System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out" exception

Comment: I assume that it works in a browser on Windows 7?

Comment: No, C# code in a desktop WinForms application.

Comment: Cornel, I think what kenny meant was; have you tried to browse to that URL in a web browser (IE, Chrome, etc) on the very same PC?  What happens? Can it connect?

Comment: Yes, in browser it works on both WinXP and Win7.

Comment: The following thread solved my issue:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859790/the-request-was-aborted-could-not-create-ssl-tls-secure-channel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try to see if System.Net tracing can provide you more information on the connection attempt,

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/asiatech/archive/2009/04/08/using-system-net-trace-to-troubleshooting-ssl-problem-in-net-2-0-application.aspx

Better collect trace files from both Windows XP and Windows 7. Compare them and you will see the cause.