# "Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel" even though SCHANNEL reports "An SSL server handshake completed successfully."

Tags: .net, https, webclient

I'm tracking down the infamous "SSL exception" from a unit test - the same exception is generated running tests under ReSharper, the nunit from the console under my account, and on the build server integration tests. Locally, the code is running from a Windows 7 machine with .NET 4.5.1 installed.

> System.Net.WebException : The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

I am fairly certain it is not *strictly* related to certificates, although they have been recently updated. (The exact time of failure is close-ish, but not definite - on the other hand, this *is* the likeliest related change across the different environments.)

IIS is setup to require client certificates and the HTTPS connection to the same endpoint is "Green" in Chrome. If I choose an invalid client certificate in Chrome I get a 403 message from IIS served up over the successfully created HTTPS connection.

Questions:

- Why does (how can) the secure SSL/TLS channel creation fail after the "handshake completed successfully"?
- Is an HTTP 403 Forbidden status response, and possible WebClient processing of such, a factor at all? If not, this inquiry path can be abandoned.
- What is a good next step in debugging the issue? Is there a certain monitorable event to indicate success (or failure) after the initial negotiation?

---

Here is what has been gathered while eliminating issues identified in other posts:

- This is the end of the exception tree; there is *no* inner "The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure" exception, which is what I *would* expect on a certificate error.
- With 'all logging' for SCHANNEL enabled the server shows

  > An *SSL server handshake completed successfully*. The negotiated
  >   cryptographic parameters are as follows.
  >
  > Protocol: TLS 1.0 / CipherSuite: 0x5 / Exchange strength: 2048
- The SSL handshake/negotiation from the failing unit test 'looks successful' on Wireshark. (It's not identical to the Chrome request and has a different negotiated CipherSuite.)
- The HTTP Client timeout is 100 seconds, which should be the default.

---

Slightly amusing, the first failing test is `ShouldCompleteSslHandshakeFor[InvalidClientCert]`.

---

UPDATE: After looking at the *local* machine's event viewer (don't ask why this just occurred to me) there are corresponding entries for the failing connections:

> (SCHANNEL) *A fatal error occurred when attempting to access the SSL client credential private key*. The error code returned from the cryptographic module is 0x8009030d. The internal error state is 10003.

This would definitely be a valid reason for why the *encrypted channel* after the handshake fails.

Comment: Does the webclient process have access to the client certificate's private key? (Right-click your cert in the MMC console -> All Tasks -> Manage Private Keys).

Comment: @Alex I just found the error in the local event viewer, so I think it's definitely something like that - I'm trying now.

Comment: @Alex We have a winner (thanks)! Only the Administrator had access; granted Read to all local users (=^_^=) fixed the exception. Now I have something to go to OPs with. I also wonder if perhaps the code to read the client certificate is not .. the best. I would have expected it to use the certs in my personal store first, and having them in both locations was put some blinders on me.

Comment: Glad I could help :), you can specify the store to open by providing the StoreLocation enum when instantiating the X509Store object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure the process accessing the client certificate has access to the certificate's private key.

> MMC Console with the Certificate Plugin -> Right Click the specified
>   certificate -> All Tasks -> Manage Private Keys.

Comment: This was indeed the problem. Lesson of the day: also look at the *local* schannel (and other event) logs.

Answer (score 2):

Answers to my questions:

> Why does (how can) the secure SSL/TLS channel creation fail after the "handshake completed successfully"?

The secure channel encryption can still fail *after* the handshake/negotiation phase, which only decides on what certs/crypto to use. In this case it was because the private key (on the client certificate) was not available due to a security restriction.

> Is an HTTP 403 Forbidden status response, and possible WebClient processing of such, a factor at all? If not, this inquiry path can be abandoned.

No. The error is caused by failing SSL/TLS encryption, before the server handler is even invoked. It was a misguided question grasping at straws.

> What is a good next step in debugging the issue? Is there a certain monitorable event to indicate success (or failure) after the initial negotiation?

Look in the relevant event logs - in this case that was the schannel logs for the *local* machine, where an critical error message was being reported. It is likely that the error would also have been found if [enabling tracing as discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12317771/the-request-was-aborted-could-not-create-ssl-tls-secure-channel).

Answer (score 1):

I tried everything here for that same message, and it turned out to be the security permissions on the MachineKeys folder (C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys) needed to be given to the users on the server.
[MSDN article with common solutions to this problem](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaushal/2012/10/07/error-hresult-0x80070520-when-adding-ssl-binding-in-iis/)