# Implementing Swedish Swish payment - C# - Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel - Certificate signing request

Tags: c#, security, ssl, iis, swish

As described in this question I'am able to connect with Swish using their test account and test certificate.

[C# HttpClient with X509Certificate2 - WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44113963/c-sharp-httpclient-with-x509certificate2-webexception-the-request-was-aborted)

However when using my own generated certificate I still get the generic error `Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel` using C# HttpClient.

I have been following these guides for Swish certificate administration:

https://www.getswish.se/content/uploads/2015/11/Guide-Certifikatsadministration_20151210.pdf

https://www.getswish.se/content/uploads/2015/06/Guide-Swish-API-170324-utan-%C3%A4ndringsmarkering.pdf

Since we are using IIS I created the certificate signing request using this: `IIS -> Server Certificates -> Create Certificate Request…`. I choose `Microsoft RSA Schannel Cryptographic Provider` with a bit length of 2048 since the documentation says it should be `PKCS#10 with 2048-bit RSA key`. My theory is that I'm doing something wrong here. Since we are developing this now and the application is not running on a domain name yet I set `Common Name` to `localhost`. Could this be the problem and If so what value should I put there for it to work from our environments? The test certificate works without a problem as I mentioned before.

After this I pasted the value from the file created at the service https://getswishcert.bankgirot.se/ and got a PKCS#7-file back (.p7b, also tried with .pem).

I then wen't to `IIS -> Server Certificates -> Complete Certificate Request…` to import the file.

When imported the `Certification Path` and everything else looks good as far as I can tell.
[image][image]

I also tried exporting the certificate to `.pfx` via `MMC -> Select certificate -> right click -> All Tasks -> Export`. Choose to export it with private key and password protected. Then imported it under `Certificates - Current User`. I can then choose the certificate in Chrome but I get the error `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR. The test certificate works in Chrome as well.

Comment: What .NET version? TLS1.2 was added in 4.5+. Most likely the bank rejects anything less. This isn't such a problem, unless you target an unsupported .NET version. The earliest supported .NET version is 4.5.2. If you have 4.0 you'll have to upgrade

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos .Net 4.5.2 and forcing TLS1.2 using `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;`. The code works with their test certificate but not with my certificate.

Comment: PS this is not a recent development either. Banks, airlines, payment providers notified everyone they'll switch to TLS1.2 two years ago, with deadlines starting 1 year ago.

Comment: why should it? Imagine I created my own self-signed certificate saying I'm the "Rotschild Bank of the Moon's Far side". Signed by me. If the bank performs certificate verification, your certificate will fail

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes I have read that. Actually many still support 1.1 as well but that is another question.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos According to their documentation I should send a CSR to them and then use that certificate. Or am i misunderstanding? https://www.getswish.se/content/uploads/2015/11/Guide-Certifikatsadministration_20151210.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out the certificate was OK. The problem was that the application was trying to connect to `https://mss.swicpc.bankgirot.se/` (test environment) with the live certificate instead of `https://swicpc.bankgirot.se/` (live).

Found with logging from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12317771/the-request-was-aborted-could-not-create-ssl-tls-secure-channel/12327881#12327881).