# Azure App Service unable to validate .pfx file: Certificate failed validation because it could not be loaded

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-web-app-service, certificate, pfx

For years I was able to upload new pfx files for SSL binding on Azure App Services using the OpenSSL creation method in [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17284371/1399567):

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out domain.name.pfx -inkey domain.name.key -in domain.name.crt
```

However, doing the same now provides this error:

> At least one certificate is not valid (Certificate failed validation because it could not be loaded.)

[image: pfx error]

What ways can this issue be resolved?

Comment: The comments on the very answer you link (now including mine) tell you that _recent_ OpenSSL (specifically 3.0.0 up) uses a different encryption for PKCS12 by default that Azure doesn't accept, and how to change it back

Answer (score 46, accepted):

## App Service private certificate requirements

App Service private certificates must meet [the following requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate?tabs=apex%2Cportal#private-certificate-requirements):

- Exported as a password-protected PFX file, encrypted using triple DES.
- Contains private key at least 2048 bits long
- Contains all intermediate certificates and the root certificate in the certificate chain.

### Option 1: Use legacy provider in OpenSSL 3+

OpenSSL 3+ no longer uses DES encryption as a default. The original command needs the `-legacy` and `-provider-path` (path to `legacy.dll`) arguments appended:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out domain.name.pfx -inkey domain.name.key -in domain.name.crt -legacy -provider-path 'C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\bin'
```

### Option 2: Let Windows re-encrypt the file

If for some reason your OpenSSL installation does not contain the legacy provider:

Open PowerShell and run this command, replacing `-FilePath` with the path to your non-working pfx file, and the password `-String` argument with its respective password:

```
Import-PfxCertificate -FilePath "pfx file path" -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'MyPassword' -AsPlainText -Force) -Exportable
```

A successful output will look like:

[image: export pfx result]

Use this thumbprint to export the cert to a new pfx file, replacing the `-Cert`, `-FilePath`, and password `-String` arguments:

```
Export-PfxCertificate -Cert Microsoft.PowerShell.Security\Certificate::LocalMachine\My\B56CE9B122FB04E29A974A4D0DB3F6EAC2D150C0 -FilePath 'newPfxName.pfx' -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'MyPassword' -AsPlainText -Force)
```

Azure should now be able to validate the new pfx file output.

Comment: And for those doing this on WSL/Linux using OpenSSL 3+, add the -legacy option:
`openssl pkcs12 -export -out certificate.pfx -inkey privateKey.key -in certificate.crt -legacy`

Comment: Thanks! TripleDES was the issue with mine.

Comment: Option 1 did not work for me on Windows - OpenSSL 3.1.1. Option 2 made the trick, thank you

Comment: Thank you @MagnusJohansson! Dropping the `-provide-path` option and keeping `-legacy` worked for me on Ubuntu/WSL.

Answer (score 2):

For me, the issue was simply solved by changing the password. My previous password had special characters, which then i changed to only alphabetic letters.

Comment: This was down-voted, but it solved my issue.  OpenSSL was generating an invalid PFX file when the password contained special characters (&@^ in my case).  I'm not sure if it was garbled by the shell or an issue with OpenSSL, but removing them worked.

Comment: I experienced this too: nonalphanumerical characters in the password prevent Azure from importing the PFX.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem using OpenSSL. I finally found that this worked for me (for a CRT file downloaded from GoDaddy).

### Convert CRT file to CER file

1. Double-click on the .crt file and click on the **Open** button in the Open File dialog.
2. Select the **Details** tab, and click on the **Copy to File** button.
3. Select Next in the Certificate Wizard.
4. Select **Base-64 encoded X.509(.CER)** and then select Next.
5. Select **Browse**, locate where you want to save your .CER file, and type in a name for your certificate.
6. Select Next and then Finished.

### Convert CER file to PFX file

1. Open the command prompt and navigate to the folder with the CER file
2. Use the Windows utility **certutil** as below (you will need to enter a password, so I prefer to come up with one first and have it to hand in notepad)

```
certutil -MergePFX cert_name.cer cert_name.pfx
```

3. Enter a password, and then confirm it (I usually find it is best to paste the password in and hit return as you will not see any characters coming up).

I was then able to use the generated PFX file to bind my App Service without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

If the specific error is

> Error adding private key certificate. At least one certificate is not
> valid (Certificate failed validation because it could not be loaded)

And if you are using the following script from OpenSSL to generate

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out forUploadToAzure.pfx -inkey privateKeyUsedToGenerateCRT.key -in certificateGenerated.crt
```

And if this is the issue, then....

OpenSSL 3 generates a longer certificate serial number when you run the pfx generation script. I would suggest downloading the OpenSSL 1 from the portal (https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html) and this should help generate a shorter certificate serial number which Azure pfx import tool will accept

Reference - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/192112/error-message-occurs-when-trying-to-upload-pfx-cer.html