# Create PFX Certificate file with OpenSSL and submitted to Azure?

Tags: azure, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I created a CSR file using OpenSSL in a MAC with the command:

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout mydomain.key -out mydomain.csr
```

Then I submitted the CSR file and received the CRT file from the SSL Certificate Provider.

After that I converted the CRT file to PFX using the OpenSSL command:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out mydomain.pfx -inkey mydomain.key -in mydomain.crt
```

I answered all the questions and defined a password.

When I submitted the PFX file to Microsoft Azure I got and error message saying the Certificate is not valid.

What am I missing? How can I find out what is wrong in the Certificate?

Comment: Are you using OpenSSL 3.0.0 up? If so dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73001634/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69343254/ . But (still) not really programming or development.