# WPF(C#) how to use a post request to transfer file?

Tags: c#, wpf, httpwebrequest

I have a picture that is presented in the form of a byte array. I need to save it to a file and send a post request. Tell me how to do it better

Here is what I do

```
private Stream file;


 public void Fun1()

  {

   using (file = IsolatedStorageHelper.OpenFile(Picture, FileMode.Create))

      {

       file.Write(bt, 0, bt.Length);
       _cookies = DataHolder.Instance.Cookies;
       HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(String.Concat("http://   Mysite.com/image.php?image=FILE",file));
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data";
            request.CookieContainer = _cookies;     
            request.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallbackPlayersfun1), request);

      }

   }

 private void GetRequestStreamCallbackPlayersfun1(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)

{

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
        Stream postStream = request.EndGetRequestStream(asynchronousResult);
 using (file = IsolatedStorageHelper.OpenFile(Picture, FileMode.Open))
        {

            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(file, Encoding.UTF8);
            byte[] buffer = br.ReadBytes(2048);
            while (buffer.Length > 0)
            {
                postStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                buffer = br.ReadBytes(2048);
            }
        }
        postStream.Close();

        request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(ReadCallbackSavePlayersfun1), request);

}

 private void ReadCallbackSavePlayersfun1(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)

{

  lock (__SYNC)

{

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);

            }
        }
```

As a result, the server did not come, tell me what am I doing wrong

---

thanks for your reply.

But I have another problem. My picture is encoded in a string, the string I write to the stream and try to send to the server. In response comes everything is OK, but the type of request is "Get"(variable respons, method ReadCallbackSavePlayersfun1). Please tell me what's wrong

```
public void Fun1()

{

string str = "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGQAAABkCAYAAA";

using (file = IsolatedStorageHelper.OpenFile(Picture, FileMode.Create))

{
                StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(file,Encoding.UTF8);
                w.WriteLine(str);
                 _cookies = DataHolder.Instance.Cookies;

                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(String.Concat("http://Mysite.com/image.php"));
                string boundary = "----------" + DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks.ToString("x", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                request.Method = "POST";
                request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
                request.CookieContainer = _cookies;


                request.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallbackPlayersfun1), request);
                w.Close();

             }

}


 private void GetRequestStreamCallbackPlayersfun1(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)

 {

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
        Stream postStream = request.EndGetRequestStream(asynchronousResult);
 string boundary = "----------" + DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks.ToString("x", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        var sbHeader = new StringBuilder();
        if (file != null)

 {
            sbHeader.AppendFormat("--{0}\r\n", boundary);
            sbHeader.AppendFormat("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"; filename=\"{1}\"\r\n", "picture", file);
            sbHeader.AppendFormat("Content-Type: {0}\r\n\r\n", request.ContentType);

}
        using (file = IsolatedStorageHelper.OpenFile(Picture, FileMode.Open))

{
            byte[] header = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sbHeader.ToString());
            byte[] footer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "--\r\n");
            long contentLength = header.Length + (file != null ? file.Length : 0) + footer.Length;

            postStream.Write(header, 0, header.Length);
 if (file != null)

{


                BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(file, Encoding.UTF8);
                byte[] buffer = br.ReadBytes(2048);
                while (buffer.Length > 0)

{
                    postStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    buffer = br.ReadBytes(2048);

 }
                br.Close();


}

            postStream.Write(footer, 0, footer.Length);
            postStream.Flush();
            postStream.Close();
}

 request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(ReadCallbackSavePlayersfun1), request);


}

  private void ReadCallbackSavePlayersfun1(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)

{
            lock (__SYNC)

{
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);

                try

{
                    String doc = "";
                    using (Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream())

 {
                        Encoding encode = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
                        StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(streamResponse, encode);
                        Char[] read = new Char[256];  
                        int count = readStream.Read(read, 0, 256);
                        while (count > 0)

{
                            String str = new String(read, 0, count);
                            doc += str;
                            count = readStream.Read(read, 0, 256);

}

}


}
                catch 
{ }

}

}
```

Comment: Are you using RESTFul Service for transfer the file ??

Answer (score 1):

Posting web byte[] data in .Net is not that simple. Saving a `byte[]` to storage is easy, so I wont have code for that, but here is the method I use to post binary data.

This is originally from http://skysanders.net/subtext/archive/2010/04/12/c-file-upload-with-form-fields-cookies-and-headers.aspx with my modifications to suit

And to get the FileInfo, simply pass in

```
new FileInfo(fullPath)
```

Good luck : )

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Create a new HttpWebRequest with the default properties for HTTP POSTS
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="url">The URL to be posted to</param>
    /// <param name="referer">The refer</param>
    /// <param name="cookies">CookieContainer that should be used in this request</param>
    /// <param name="postData">The post data</param>
    private string CreateHttpWebUploadRequest(string url, string referer, CookieContainer cookies, NameValueCollection postData, FileInfo fileData, string fileContentType)
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
        string boundary = "----------" + DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks.ToString("x", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        // set the request variables
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
        request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
        request.CookieContainer = cookies;
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/533.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/5.0.375.55 Safari/533.4";
        request.Accept = "image/gif, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, image/pjpeg, */*";
        request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate");
        request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip;
        request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language: en-us");
        request.Referer = referer;
        request.KeepAlive = true;
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

        // process through the fields
        var sbHeader = new StringBuilder();

        // add form fields, if any
        if (postData != null)
        {
            foreach (string key in postData.AllKeys)
            {
                string[] values = postData.GetValues(key);
                if (values != null) 
                {
                    foreach (string value in values)
                    {
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                            sbHeader.AppendFormat("--{0}\r\n", boundary);
                            sbHeader.AppendFormat("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\";\r\n\r\n{1}\r\n", key, value);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (fileData != null)
        {
            sbHeader.AppendFormat("--{0}\r\n", boundary);
            sbHeader.AppendFormat("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"; filename=\"{1}\"\r\n", "media", fileData.Name);
            sbHeader.AppendFormat("Content-Type: {0}\r\n\r\n", fileContentType);
        }

        byte[] header = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sbHeader.ToString());
        byte[] footer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "--\r\n");
        long contentLength = header.Length + (fileData != null ? fileData.Length : 0) + footer.Length;

        // set content length
        request.ContentLength = contentLength;

        // ref http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859790/the-request-was-aborted-could-not-create-ssl-tls-secure-channel
        // avoid The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel exception
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;

        using (var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            requestStream.Write(header, 0, header.Length);

            // write the uploaded file
            if (fileData != null)
            {
                // write the file data, if any
                byte[] buffer = new Byte[fileData.Length];
                var bytesRead = fileData.OpenRead().Read(buffer, 0, (int)(fileData.Length));
                requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }

            // write footer
            requestStream.Write(footer, 0, footer.Length);
            requestStream.Flush();
            requestStream.Close();

            using (var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            using (var stIn = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                return stIn.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
```