# The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel - SecurityProtocol behavior

Tags: c#, .net, ssl-certificate, ssl

After installing certificate into `Local Computer` storage of `Trusted Root Certification Authorities` the .NET `WebRequest` still throws:

```
The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel
```

`ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol` now contains `SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3` | `SecurityProtocolType.Tls`.

After reading Simon Dugré's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2904963/121968, I have set:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
```

It works ok. 
After setting back:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
```

it still **works ok**. I have two questions:

1. Why it still works? Is there sort of caching?
2. And why it was previously working just with flag `Ssl3` only and not
   with both `Ssl3` and `Tls`?

Answer (score 1):

There is SSL/TLS session resumption, probably that's your case.
Maybe you do not have shared TLS1 ciphersuites.
The best way to check is to run Wireshark, and see SSL packets for your connection, they are very good explained in Wireshark.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to add the lines:

```
 ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = True
 ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 Or SecurityProtocolType.Tls
```