# The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel Exception

Tags: c#, exception, iis, service, web

Let me explain my situation.

I created a self-signed certificate and installed it in the **Trusted Root Certification Authorities** section in MMC.

I then created two certificates using the self-signed certificate:

1. A certificate with subject name "localhost"
2. A certificate with subject name "test.com"

I then installed both certificates into the **Personal** certificates section in MMC.

I then deployed a web service as HTTPS (SSL with accept client certificates) in IIS.  The certificate used to deploy the web service is the one with subject name "localhost".

Now, I have a client who wants to connect to the web service.  I successfully added a web reference to the service.  This is the code:

```
            ClientServices web_service = new ClientServices();
            X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
            X509Certificate2Collection col = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, "test.com", true);

            if (col.Count == 1)
            {
                ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
                ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
                web_service.ClientCertificates.Add(col[0]);

                try
                {
                    string hello = web_service.HelloWorld();
                    int add = web_service.add(4, 31);
                    int sub = web_service.subtract(30, 10);

                    Console.WriteLine(hello);
                    Console.WriteLine(add);
                    Console.WriteLine(sub);
                }
                catch (WebException e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message.ToString());
                }
            }

            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The certificate was not found!");
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
```

As you can see, I am sending the "test.com" certificate along with the web service request.  Unfortunately, I am getting this exception:

```
The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel
```

How can I solve this problem?  I have already wasted 3 hours on this issue.  Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private void Somewhere() {
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AllwaysGoodCertificate);
}

private static bool AllwaysGoodCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors policyErrors) {
   return true;
}
```

Source:
[The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859790/the-request-was-aborted-could-not-create-ssl-tls-secure-channel)

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I managed to solve the problem by beginning from scratch with generating the certificates all over again.  It then worked perfectly.  I don't know why but then it worked.