# Security protocol per httpclient/request (HttpClient)

Tags: c#, tls1.2, dotnet-httpclient

I have the same problem as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27953681/5965412).

```
var handler = new WebRequestHandler();
handler.ClientCertificates.Add(cacert2);
var client = new HttpClient(handler, true);
var result = await client.PostAsync(uri, content); //tls 1.0
```

This request to the service works only with default SecurityProtocol (TLS).

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls; //default .net 4.5
```

If i use

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

, the service displays the error `400 No required SSL certificate was sent`.

How to set a protocol for each httpclient?

Comment: Make sure you can access the URL with an ordinary browser. The browser should prompt you to choose a client cert. It's possible your cert won't show up, e.g. if it lacks a private key, has a root authority that the server doesn't support, or the user account lacks permissions to the key store for the certificate. That will be a clue that your code is not the problem.

Comment: Browser prompt displayed. It's work, but only with Tls1.0.