# Zip file download corrupted

Tags: c#, file, download, zip

I have a problem with the ".zip" file download. I want to make a game launcher and I need to add the game download and install feature. When I download the packed game with `ZipFile.DownloadFile` from the server it gets corrupted.

This is the code:

```
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
```

---

```
// Installation folder will be set in the folder browse dialog
string installationFolder;

// I don't want to show the download url but its in Mediafire 
// and I tried to download it from Google Drive
string remoteUri = "the .zip file url";
string fileName = "gamename.zip", myStringWebResource = null;

// Create a new WebClient instance.
WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();

// Concatenate the domain with the Web resource filename.
myStringWebResource = remoteUri + fileName;

// Download the Web resource and save it into the current filesystem folder.
myWebClient.DownloadFile(remoteUri, Application.StartupPath + "/gamesdownload/" + fileName);

ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(Application.StartupPath + "/gamesdownload/gamename.zip", installationFolder);
```

What is wrong with the code?

Comment: Removed Visual Studio 2017 tag

Comment: "but its in Mediafire" - what happens if you take the link to the zip file and open it in an incognito/private browsing session? I suspect you're actually downloading a redirect page intended for humans. If this isn't the case, then you should use a tool like `VBinDiff` to compare the expected zip file to the downloaded zip file.

Comment: can u share the link so that we can see if it works ?

Comment: It works fine if I download it myself, but if I download it with `ZipFile.DownloadFile` code it corrupts the file.

Comment: OK, can we get an [mcve]

Comment: Can I have a code that downloads a zip file without corrupting it?

Comment: Or what is the problem?

Comment: @Marakusa can't you try to download another zip, that perhaps is less sensitive to you and you may be willing to share with us?

Comment: Ok there you go. Working zip: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1AwH0yI56OU_sarWsy5RPlaGTUkwYqTMm
And corrupted: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1uykT10coYRWSqhym1SZaLEHViYlbmad3

Comment: The "corrupted" zip file is actually an HTML file.

Comment: I renamed it from .zip to .html and opened it: https://i.imgur.com/72dWrEx.png

Comment: Umm... ok, so the problem is in the code?

Comment: The problem is either that `remoteUri` doesn't contain the full zipfile URL, or more likely, mediafire redirects the browser to a page before allowing you to download the file. As I originally commented.

Comment: So what should I use?

Comment: I suggest you get the file manually (using for example Chrome) and look at the network traffic (use the F12 dev tools). You need to find that one URL that gets you the file. Then do the same thing with your program; you can inspect the traffic with [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler). Compare the two requests and account for any differences between them. My guess is that the request for the ZIP file requires you send along some cookies or other data or else you get the HTML file instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer!
I changed from Mediafire to GitHub!
And this is the solution for the error that comes:
[The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859790/the-request-was-aborted-could-not-create-ssl-tls-secure-channel)