# HttpWebRequest returns error in c#, works in simple php example

Tags: c#, .net, system.net.httpwebrequest

I have working php example, which does its job, but can not make the same in .NET - returning

> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel. at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context) at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream() at

php code:

```
$curl = curl_init();
$post_fields = "xxxxxx&msg_type=aaa";
$submit_url = "https://ecommerce.........";
Curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 1); //0 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, '0');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLCERT,         getcwd().'/sert.pem');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLKEYPASSWD,   'XXXXXXXX');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $submit_url);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
$info = curl_getinfo($curl);
```

.NET Code

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
string addr1 = "https://ecommerce......";
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(addr1);

req.Method = "POST"; // Post method
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
    delegate
    {
        return true; // **** Always accept
    };

req.KeepAlive = false;
req.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;

//Certificate with private key
string certName = "sss.xxx.ee_5300954_merchant_wp";
string certpwd = "xxxxxxxx";
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(@"c:\xxx\xxx\" + certName + ".pem", certpwd);

req.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
    delegate
    {
        return true; // **** Always accept
    };

req.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);

//req.PreAuthenticate = false;

string langStr = "";
String XML = "description=xxxx&msg_type=SMS";//reader.ReadToEnd();

byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(XML);
req.ContentLength = buffer.Length;

// Wrap the request stream with a text-based writer

Stream writer = req.GetRequestStream();
writer.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
writer.Close();

WebResponse rsp = req.GetResponse();
String post_response = "";
using (StreamReader responseStream = new StreamReader(rsp.GetResponseStream()))
{
}
```

I have tried many variations of ignoring cert errors, or playing with tls ssl ver sions etc, but none seems to be working I have tried many variations of ignoring cert errors, or playing with tls ssl ver sions etc, but none seems to be working.

(about duplication suggestions, I think I've tried them all, none solved my issue)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859790/the-request-was-aborted-could-not-create-ssl-tls-secure-channel)

Comment: i tried this too, did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but turns out sometimes specifying correct ContentLength might cause this problem.
Just removing req.ContentLength = buffer.Length; 
solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

PHP either trust your server-side or skips TLS verification, this is why it works. How do you test it? Is API at the same machine that you are sending requests from?
Check this out, maybe it will help since the error is quite unusual. https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/980817/fix-a-net-framework-3-5-based-application-becomes-unresponsive-when-a

Comment: To test, I am doing GetResponse(), which returns mentioned error. That link did not help. Php version works perfect, I just need to reproduce it in .NET.
It's being posted to remote server, Bank endpoint.