# Occasionally getting error: "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel."

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have a problem with my .NET Windows Client Application. Occasionally, about 1 out of 100 web service calls, I get the error:

> The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

**When does the error show?**

- In Windows 7, but not in Windows 10
- When using Fiddler, the error does not occur.

**I have tried the following**

- Upgraded from .NET framework 4.5 to 4.8
- Tried different Security Protocol settings with ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol. ([The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859790/the-request-was-aborted-could-not-create-ssl-tls-secure-channel))
- I have tried to uninstall windows security patches from this period to see if it has anything to do with those.

Now I'm running out of ideas and I can't find anyone else with a similar problem.

Please help me, I'm desperate. :)

Comment: Can you show us some code please? Do you use "ServicePointManager" for this?

Comment: If it never happens on Windows 10 but occasionally on Windows 7 then it might be a timing issue. Is the Windows 7 system slower than the Windows 10 system? Does it has less cores? Tried something silly like placing a Thread.Sleep(100); right before making the connection. It could also be a race condition between multiple threads. Without code, I just have to guess... :-)

Comment: 1) The networking is unreliable, so you need to implement retry mechanism. 2) Fiddler is almost useless in this case, as it can hide SSL/TLS handshakes from you. Use a tool like Wireshark to capture/analyze the handshake packets when the issue recurs, and the culprit should reveal itself.