# C# JIRA Error Message: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: ssl, jira

When I run this it works and gives a valid reponse

```
private readonly Lazy<Jira> jiraClient = new Lazy<Jira>(() => Jira.CreateRestClient("https://jira...", "name", "pass"));
```

but when I try to run this I get an error.

```
Issue issue = await this.jiraClient.Value.Issues.GetIssueAsync(jiraId);
```

```
Error Message: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the answer
[The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859790/the-request-was-aborted-could-not-create-ssl-tls-secure-channel)

ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

Comment: you can add this in the constructor