# c# : Unable to call web service after the certificate is regenerated on same domain

Tags: c#, ssl, ssl-certificate

I use my C# application to call a web service of an internal domain `xxx.com` and it has been working fine.

But now this internal server is destroyed, they recreated the machine with the same domain, and they generated a new certificate for this domain.

Now, when I call the same web service on their machine, I get error : `Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.`

I want to know why it stops working, and how could I make the call now (to renew the certificate?how?)

Thank you.

Comment: They've probably enabled TLS 1.2 on the new one. Try this solution [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2904963/2174170)

Comment: How long did the service run? Have you checked the SSL/TLS configuration? Maybe they have changed it within the new setup

Comment: @Dumisani how do I know the TLS version ? I click on the padlock on chrome and in certificate I get V3, but I suppose it's SSL V3

Comment: Then you might have to use `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3` in your case

Comment: TLS has different versions.  See : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security

Comment: Has the new certificate been installed on your client?