# WebClient.DownloadData method crashing the application

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

This below is all my code which is a copy paste from Web API book I am reading.

```
public class PageSizeController : ApiController
{
    private static string TargetUrl = "http://apress.com";

    public long GetPageSize()
    {
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        byte[] apressData = wc.DownloadData(TargetUrl);
        Debug.WriteLine("Elapsed Time: ", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        return apressData.LongLength;
        }
    }
}
```

When I make the API call : http://localhost:38000/api/pagesize

It throw this exception on `DownloadData` method:

> System.Net.WebException: 'The request was aborted: Could not create
>   SSL/TLS secure channel.'

This is not very welcoming when you open a book to follow the examples and it just doesn't work for their HelloWorld application.

Comment: If you google for this message you'll find that this is caused by the lack of support for TLS1.2 on the OS/runtime you use. There are a *lot* of duplicate SO questions about this. By now, almost all major services have stopped supporting anything less than TLS1.2 . What .NET Runtime and OS are you targeting?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859790/the-request-was-aborted-could-not-create-ssl-tls-secure-channel)

Comment: In fact, all browsers will ditch TLS 1.1 and lower in less than a month.

Comment: You're probably using an unsupported and upatched OS or an unsupported .NET runtime. *Supported* Windows OS versions work with TLS 1.2 already, and .NET 4.6+ will use the OS's highest supported TLS version. The earliest supported .NET version is .NET 4.5.2

Comment: But I am on Windows 10, VS 2019 and Targeting .NET 4.5