# Cannot create secure SSL/TLS channel in API request

Tags: c#, api, ssl, webclient

I'm kinda desperate here. I had an application who was working just fine. It's supposed to connect to an API to recover some quotes and orders to import them on an ERP.

But recently the nginx server on which the data is stored has been updated and since then I cannot get the data. I've upgraded my framework to 4.7 cause it's supposed to handle the TLS connexions parameters on its own (from what I've understand at least I may be wrong I'm not really familiar with all of this).

But I still have the same error message : Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

Do you have any suggestions regarding this issue ?

Cheers.

Comment: Your question leaves a lot to guesswork. Maybe, you can check, which TLS protocols/algorithms the server supports, and which are supported by your client. If they don't have any in common, the connection will not work. Also, please check other questions with similar error messages, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859790/the-request-was-aborted-could-not-create-ssl-tls-secure-channel

Comment: The Nginx must’ve been configured to not support old and weak protocols and ciphers anymore. Try changing `System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol` to include TLS1.2 and TLS1.3 (if applicable for your .net framework version).

Comment: I was in a rush yesterday and I kinda forget to say that I've tried to force the Security protocol to include TLS1.2 and I've got the same error message when I tried this. 
I've also exchanged with one of the guy who works on the nginx server and he told me that the server supported TLS1.2 so that's why I'm kinda lost cause even though I force it to be TLS 1.2 in my code I get the error message. 
I'll try and browse some more on the questions with the same message but I've done it before and it didn't really help me, hence my post.
Cheers !