# C# Windows Service ,The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel with SecurityProtocol

Tags: c#, json, windows, api, service

So We have windows service api that gets data then send to web using webclient
the problem is we have this certain branch that sends error while other branches api are working fine except for this one branch that sends error:

"The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel"

i have added

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

yet the error still occured , please help and thankyou

[heres the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYdz0.jpg)

Comment: When you say "branch" do you mean a code branch in eg a git repo?

Comment: var request = webclient.uploadvalues(website url, namevaluecollection data to be pass) 

its data to be pass to web

Comment: @CaiusJard I guess by "branch" they mean "route", "specific request url"

Comment: It's [not recomended](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient#remarks) to use `WebClient` (see Remarks section)

Comment: @vasily.sib I did also wonder if it's a physical location like "the London office", "the New York store" etc

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you already followed the top voted here:         [The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859790/the-request-was-aborted-could-not-create-ssl-tls-secure-channel)

Try to extend you tls protocols like this, so that it can fallback to previous versions if the server does not support them:

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls
               | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11
               | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
               | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
```

If it doesn't work still, try the answer by User:APW with extra troubleshooting steps.