# Windows Server 2016 IIS 10 WCF service call fails with "Could not establish secure channel"

Tags: wcf, iis, iis-10, iis-8.5, ejbca

I have a .NET 4.5 web application that runs fine on a Windows Server 2012 R2 machine, however it won't function when deployed on a Windows Server 2016 machine.

The application interacts with a rather old Ejbca installation utilizing its web service interface.
The application works perfectly fine when deployed on a Windows Server 2012 R2 machine in IIS 8.5.9600.
When deployed on a newer machine - Windows Server 2016 in IIS 10.0, any calls to that web service fail with the following exception:

```
<InnerException>
   <HelpLink i:nil="true"/>
   <InnerException i:nil="true"/>
   <Message>The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel</Message>
   <StackTrace>at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   </StackTrace>
   <Type>System.Net.WebException</Type>
</InnerException>
```

What could be the reason for this behavior?

Comment: You can refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859790/the-request-was-aborted-could-not-create-ssl-tls-secure-channel

Comment: Use a tool like Wireshark to analyze the TLS handshake packets. That can tell you more on what's wrong and how to fix that.