# WebException:The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: c#, .net, windows, httpwebrequest

Facing this issuer since window was upgraded

Environment : Windows 2012 R2
.Net Framework : 4.6.1
TLS 1.1,1.2 configured, Registry entry added

Still Error persist if we visit few links[few will work, few won’t]
Error details:

```
System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at WindowsFormsApplication.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\WindowsFormsApplication\WindowsFormsApplication\Form1.cs:line 51
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.

Can some one suggest how we can fix this issue

**It works with 2019 R2 it works**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859790/the-request-was-aborted-could-not-create-ssl-tls-secure-channel)

Comment: @Wh1t3rabbit this issue exit mainly with windows 2012 R2 .