# The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel - Decrypt returned SEC_I_RENEGOTIATE

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, wcf-security, wcf-client

Our application consumes a web service in C# (.Net framework 3.5). Getting the correct response from the server most of the time, but it is intermittently throwing an error:

```
The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
```

Having enabled the traces it shows:

```
System.Net Error: 0 : [3688] Decrypt returned SEC_I_RENEGOTIATE.
```

Has anyone faced this issue before? What is a fix to this problem. please let me know.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

-Jemo

Comment: there is already similar post here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232746/c-sharp-httpwebrequest-sec-i-renegotiate-intermittent-errors

Comment: Have you checked that the (UTC) clock is the same between the machines?