# HTTPWebRequest Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, httpwebrequest

I am trying to call a Web API using HttpWebRequest(Console Application).
To upload the file, I am using the code snippet provided by @Cristian Romanescu ont this question **[Upload files with HTTPWebrequest (multipart/form-data)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566462/upload-files-with-httpwebrequest-multipart-form-data)** 

If I set the req.ProtocolVersion as HttpVersion.Version10,I get Bad request when I try to do req.GetResponseStream().

If i set the req.ProtocolVersion as HttpVersion.Version11,I get **Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.**  when i try to do req.GetResponseStream().

If tried to post the data using POSTMAN, but even Postman says **Could not get any response".**

If I try to hit the URL using IE-11 I get HTTP 404.[I know i am not posting the actual file], but Chrome displays the custom/appropriate error message.

I tried the solutions already provided on stackoverflow, but unfortunately they do not solve my problem.

Thankyou.

Comment: 404?? Not found, maybe something with server iis ?

Comment: @LeonBarkan : Chrome displays appropriate error message, IE shows HTTP 404

Comment: maybe you need certificate from your server to be installed at client side ?

Comment: @LeonBarkan : I do have the certificate installed on client side. Found the solution, see my answer. Thanks for your inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things that I was doing wrong.

1. The Server wanted date in yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss, I was providing the date in yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.ssss Format(DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("o")). This was the cause of **Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel**
2. The server wanted the parameters in request body as well. I had passed the parameters only as query string. This was the cause of HTTP 404

In the process, I had asked a guy outside my team to help. He had asked me to see if there were any SSL related errors. To do this he asked me to add 
`System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AcceptAllCertifications);` and define `AcceptAllCertifications`, which was not the case. So to resolve the issue, I had to take care of the things mentioned above.

Answer (score 4):

Which solution you have tried? It's worth trying the following if you haven't already - write following before you actually invoke the service:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Comment: I think SSL3 is no longer considered secure. For more info https://stackoverflow.com/a/6584992/6190900

Comment: Thanks Joseph for making aware about SSL3. I have updated answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create self signed certificate from your server and add it to your client machine.

[Create self signed certificate (Server side)](https://documentation.meraki.com/zGeneral_Administration/Other_Topics/Installing_a_Self-Signed_Certificate_on_Windows_Server)

[Import self signed certificate (Client side)](https://pubs.vmware.com/flex-1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.horizon.flex.admin.doc%2FGUID-4F29CCE6-2F04-461D-81EF-C1480B1A8E84.html)