# "Run as Administrator" (System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.)

Tags: c#, windows-10, system.net.webexception, bayeux

I am getting the WebException error only on 2 PCs (i tryed 5 diferent PCs).
The problem does not occure if i start application "As administrator".

I have tryed to add

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
```

and also change diferent flags for certificate

```
X509Certificate2 Cert = new X509Certificate2(fileName, "", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);
```

But it didn't help.

```
    try
    {
        string webLink = @"https://" + destinationIP + "/apps/MMC/";
        //get firmware version of trellisware radio
        string fileName = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "etc" + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "default.p12";
        X509Certificate2 Cert = new X509Certificate2(fileName, "", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);
        CertificateWebClient myWebClient = new CertificateWebClient(Cert);
        string webData = myWebClient.DownloadString(webLink);
        Uri responseUri = myWebClient.ResponseUri;

        string[] response = responseUri.ToString().Split('/');
    }
    catch (WebException ws) 
    { 
        logger.Error("WebException: " + webLink + Environment.NewLine + ws);
    }
    catch (SocketException) { }
    catch (ThreadAbortException) { }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logger.Error("Exception: " + webLink + Environment.NewLine + ex);
    }

    public class CertificateWebClient : WebClient
    {
        private readonly X509Certificate2 certificate;

        public CertificateWebClient(X509Certificate2 cert)
        {
            certificate = cert;
        }

        protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(address);

            System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate (Object obj, X509Certificate X509certificate, X509Chain chain, System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors errors)
            {
                return true;
            };

            request.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);
            return request;
        }

        Uri _responseUri;

        public Uri ResponseUri
        {
            get { return _responseUri; }
        }

        protected override WebResponse GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
        {
            WebResponse response = base.GetWebResponse(request);
            _responseUri = response.ResponseUri;
            return response;
        }
    }
```

Exceptions:

```
2019-05-13 07:04:48.0050 | Error | OManager | WebException: https://169.1.28.23/apps/MMC/
System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& request)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(Uri address)
   at CAstralPilot.OcelotManager.<>c__DisplayClass26_0.<getGCSTrelliswareVersion>b__0() in 


2019-05-13 07:04:48.2081 | Warn | Genesys.Bayeux.Client | Request transport failed. Retrying after 00:00:00 Exception: 
Genesys.Bayeux.Client.BayeuxTransportException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.ClientWebSocket.<ConnectAsyncCore>d__21.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.WebSockets.ClientWebSocket.<ConnectAsyncCore>d__21.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Genesys.Bayeux.Client.WebSocketTransport.<Open>d__12.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Genesys.Bayeux.Client.WebSocketTransport.<Open>d__12.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Genesys.Bayeux.Client.ConnectLoop.<Poll>d__16.MoveNext()
```

I expected the code to work on al PCs, why some of them need administrator rights so WebClient can connect?
Do i need to add certificate on some trusted location so it can work?

Comment: First step in debugging something like this is to navigate to the URL from a browser on the failing machine(s) and see what that yields.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600743/could-not-create-ssl-tls-secure-channel-could-the-problem-be-a-proxy-server

Comment: I have checked "certificate MMC" and certificate is signed and have full control on all users. The browsers like firefox and chrome can open the URL and ask for certificate which works. Only my C# application doesn't want to create the connection if its not started "As administrator"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12317771/the-request-was-aborted-could-not-create-ssl-tls-secure-channel/12327881#12327881

Comment: I found out that i also have .pem certificat and not only .p12, when i used .pem the application stared to work on all PCs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to add certificate in
Manage user certificate (certmgr)
and
Manage computer certificate (certlm)