# Always getting "System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel." whenever we do deployment

Tags: wcf, x509certificate

**we have a wcf service which consume different service using X509Certificate2.
we have installed certificate in personal store (.pfx) and we are exporting .cer in a folder to use while calling the different service.
whenever i redeploy the WCF application, System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

once i reinstall the pfx and export again, it will start working again.**

Comment: Is your WCF service deployed in IIS?

Comment: About the cause of this error, you can refer to this link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600743/could-not-create-ssl-tls-secure-channel-could-the-problem-be-a-proxy-server

Comment: @DingPeng no it is self hoste

Comment: If it is self-hosted and used for certificate verification, the certificate needs to be bound to the corresponding service port. Will the service port be modified when the WCF application is redeployed? We need to know what will be affected by redeploying WCF applications.

Comment: @DingPeng WCF service is consuming another service using certificate. there is no change in service port while redeployin. i didn't see this particlar certificate bounded to a service port in another servers.

Comment: Does redeployment mean re-running the self-hosted WCF service?