# How to solve "Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority"

Tags: .net, wcf, iis, certificate

I have a WCF service hosted in IIS 7 using HTTPS. When I browse to this site in Internet Explorer, it works like a charm, this is because I *have* added the certificate to the local root certificate authority store.

I'm developing on 1 machine, so client and server are same machine. The certificate is self-signed directly from IIS 7 management snap in.

I continually get this error now...

> Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority.

... when called from client console.

I manually gave myself permissions and network service to the certificate, using `findprivatekey` and using `cacls.exe`.

I tried to connect to the service using SOAPUI, and that works, so it must be an issue in my client application, which is code based on what used to work with http.

Where else can I look I seem to have exhausted all possibilities as to why I can't connect?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Could not establish trust relationship for SSL/TLS secure channel -- SOAP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/703272/could-not-establish-trust-relationship-for-ssl-tls-secure-channel-soap)

Comment: If you have control of the creation of the certificates, don't forget about "Alternate Subject Name".  Like you could put a wild card in "*.full.domainname.com".  See https://www.digicert.com/subject-alternative-name.htm

Answer (score 211, accepted):

As a workaround you could add a handler to the `ServicePointManager`'s `ServerCertificateValidationCallback` on the client side:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
    (se, cert, chain, sslerror) =>
        {
            return true;
        };
```

but be aware that ***this is not a good practice*** as it completely ignores the server certificate and tells the service point manager that whatever certificate is fine which can seriously compromise client security. You could refine this and do some custom checking (for certificate name, hash etc).
at least you can circumvent problems during development when using test certificates.

Comment: I think most public setups will use a purchased cert but during dev use the above code within conditional #if statements. Enterprise devs should generally setup an internal CA server >> http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc875810.aspx

Comment: Helped me figure out how to get my SSL WCF call working with Fiddler2 for debugging.

Comment: @karank Consider putting it in the Application_Start method in the Global.asax (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/12507094/1175419). I would strongly recommend using a #if DEBUG compiler directive or something similar as mentioned in Luke's comment.

Comment: Awesome! you can use lambda expression as System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (se, cert, chain, sslerror) => true;

Comment: A little extra explanation can be found here : http://blog.effectivemessaging.com/2015_09_01_archive.html

Comment: OP: be aware ***this is not good practise***. Developers of the world: ***we don't care gives me teh codez!11***...

Comment: This is a good workaround (or you call Bypass) for the time being. But yeah really need to get the certificate.

Comment: On Net Core 3.1 I soved the problem with this solution:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52908503/wcf-in-asp-net-core-2-0-could-not-establish-trust-relationship-for-the-ssl-tls

Answer (score 48):

When I have this problem it is because the client.config had its endpoints like:

```
 https://myserver/myservice.svc
```

but the certificate was expecting

```
 https://myserver.mydomain.com/myservice.svc
```

Changing the endpoints to match the FQDN of the server resolves my problem. I know this is not the only cause of this problem.

Comment: I just had this issue again and this time it had to with the wrong certificate being used. It seems like in both cases it has to do with matching up names properly.

Comment: My auto generated configuration had                          <endpoint address="https://localhost/myservice.svc" changing this to <endpoint address="https://mymachine.mydoman.com/myservice.svc" resolved this.

Comment: This was absolutely my issue and it took me two days to find your answer. +1, I would give you +1000 if I could.

Answer (score 23):

Your problem arises because you're using a self signed key. The client does not trust this key, nor does the key itself provide a chain to validate or a certificate revocation list.

You have a few options - you can

1. turn off certificate validation on
   the client (bad move, man in the
   middle attacks abound)
2. use makecert to create a root CA and
   create certificates from that (ok
   move, but there is still no CRL)
3. create an internal root CA using
   Windows Certificate Server or other
   PKI solution then trust that root
   cert (a bit of a pain to manage)
4. purchase an SSL certificate from one
   of the trusted CAs (expensive)

Comment: Regarding (4), [StartSSL](http://www.startssl.com/) will actually give you a free Class 1 certificate that works in all major browsers.  They work great for me for my half a dozen low bandwidth sites.

Comment: I think #2 on this list...this url might help : https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/jhoward/2005/02/02/how-to-use-makecert-for-trusted-root-certification-authority-and-ssl-certificate-issuance/#comment-34025  "How-to use MakeCert for trusted root certification authority and SSL certificate issuance"

Comment: Note: StartCom is no longer trustworthy - and has just been removed from Chrome https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StartCom

Answer (score 22):

If you use .net core try this:

```
client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.SslCertificateAuthentication =
        new X509ServiceCertificateAuthentication()
        {
            CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None,
            RevocationMode = System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509RevocationMode.NoCheck
        };
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But it has nothing to do with .net core. It's an universal recipe :)

Answer (score 21):

the first two use lambda, the third uses regular code... hope you find it helpful

```
            //Trust all certificates
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
                ((sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true);

            // trust sender
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback
                = ((sender, cert, chain, errors) => cert.Subject.Contains("YourServerName"));

            // validate cert by calling a function
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateRemoteCertificate);

    // callback used to validate the certificate in an SSL conversation
    private static bool ValidateRemoteCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate cert, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors policyErrors)
    {
        bool result = false;
        if (cert.Subject.ToUpper().Contains("YourServerName"))
        {
            result = true;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: //Trust all certificates
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (se, cert, chain, sslerror) =>
            {
                return true;
            };

            // trust sender
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (se, cert, chain, sslerror) =>
            {
                return cert.Subject.Contains("ca-l-9wfvrm1.ceridian.ca");
            };

Comment: Any cracker could forge a certificate passing all the above tests. This is unsecure.

Answer (score 21):

A one line solution. Add this anywhere before calling the server on the client side:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += delegate { return true; };
```

This should only be used for testing purposes because the client will skip SSL/TLS security checks.

Comment: A brilliant workaround for testing.  We are consuming a service whose provider has made security a living hell with a convoluted chain of security certificates and until we can get their wonky certs and chaining to work properly, this workaround is the only thing allowing us to continue development.

Answer (score 15):

I encountered the same problem and I was able to resolve it with two solutions:
First, I used the MMC snap-in "Certificates" for the "Computer account" and dragged the self-signed certificate into the "Trusted Root Certification Authorities" folder. This means the local computer (the one that generated the certificate) will now trust that certificate.
Secondly I noticed that the certificate was generated for some internal computer name, but the web service was being accessed using another name. This caused a mismatch when validating the certificate. We generated the certificate for computer.operations.local, but accessed the web service using https://computer.internaldomain.companydomain.com. When we switched the URL to the one used to generate the certificate we got no more errors.

Maybe just switching URLs would have worked, but by making the certificate trusted you also avoid the red screen in Internet Explorer where it tells you it doesn't trust the certificate.

Comment: This didn't work for me initially. I had to make one modification to the steps above: When dragging the certificate, make sure to hold down the Ctrl key so that the certificate is _copied_, not _moved_ from _Personal/Certificates_ to _Trusted Root Certification Authorities/Certificates_.

Answer (score 7):

Please do following steps:

1. Open service link in IE.
2. Click on the certificate error mention in address bar and click on View certificates.
3. Check issued to: name.
4. Take the issued name and replace localhost mention in service and client endpoint base address name with A fully qualified domain name (FQDN).

For Example: https://**localhost**:203/SampleService.svc 
To https://**INL-126166-.groupinfra.com**:203/SampleService.svc

Comment: Great, thanks for this answer ! Solved the issues without making any code changes.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to the answers above, you could encounter this error if your client is running the wrong TLS version, for example if the server is only running TLS 1.2.

You can fix it by using:

```
// tested in .NET 4.5:
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Comment: in my case accepted answer didn't help me, but this one did a trick

Comment: This is the only answer which corrected the error in my case.

Comment: Also this was the trick that helped me, although with .Net 4.7.2

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. I also had added CA certificates in the local store, but I did in the WRONG way.

Using mmc Console (Start -> Run -> **mmc** ) you should add **Certificates** snap-in as Service account (choosing the service account of IIS) or Computer account (it adds for every account on the machine)

Here an image of what I'm talking about
 [image: Add snap-in for a service account or the computer account]

From here now, you can add certificates of CAs (**Trusted Root CAs** and **Intermediate CAs**), and everything will work fine

Answer (score 4):

I had similar issue with self-signed certificate.
I could resolve it by using the certificate name same as FQDN of the server.

Ideally, SSL part should be managed at the server side. Client is not required to install any certificate for SSL. Also, some of the posts mentioned about bypassing the SSL from client code. But I totally disagree with that.

Answer (score 4):

I just dragged the certificate into the "Trusted Root Certification Authorities" folder and voila everything worked nicely.

Oh. And I first added the following from a Administrator Command Prompt:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=https://+:8732/Servicename user=NT-MYNDIGHET\INTERAKTIV
```

I am not sure of the name you need for the user (mine is norwegian as you can see !):
   `user=NT-AUTHORITY/INTERACTIVE` ?

You can see all existing urlacl's by issuing the command: `netsh http show urlacl`

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted to add something to the answer of @NMrt who already pointed out:

> you could encounter this error if your client is running the wrong TLS version, for example if the server is only running TLS 1.2.

With Framework 4.7.2, if you do not explicitly configure the target framework in your web.config like this

```
<system.web>
  <compilation targetFramework="4.7" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7" />
</system.web>
```

your system default security protocols will be ignored and something "lower" might be used instead. In my case Ssl3/Tls instead of Tls13.

- You can fix this also in code by setting the SecurityProtocol (keeps other protocols working):

  ```
  System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls11;
  System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol &= ~System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
  ```
- or even by adding registry keys to enable or disable strong crypto

  ```
  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
  "SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001
  ```

This blog post pointed me to the right direction and explains the backgrounds better than I can:

https://www.ryadel.com/en/asp-net-client-server-cannot-comunicate-because-they-possess-common-algorithm-how-to-fix-c-sharp/

Answer (score 0):

This occurred when trying to connect to the WCF Service via. the IP e.g. `https://111.11.111.1:port/MyService.svc` while using a certificate tied to a name e.g. mysite.com.

Switching to the `https://mysite.com:port/MyService.svc` resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

This occurred when trying to connect to the WCF Service using only host name e.g. https://host/MyService.svc while using a certificate tied to a name e.g. host.mysite.com.

Switching to the https://host.mysite.com/MyService.svc and this resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

Just fixed a similar issue.

I realized I had an application pool that was running under an account that only had reading permission over the certificate that it was used.

The .NET application could correctly retrieve the certificate but that exception was thrown only when GetRequestStream() was called.

Certificates permissions can be managed via [MMC console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14337947/manage-private-keys-option-missing)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .net core, then during development you can bypass certificate validation by using compiler directives. This way will only validate certificate for release and not for debug:

```
#if (DEBUG)
        client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.SslCertificateAuthentication =
                new X509ServiceCertificateAuthentication()
                {
                    CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None,
                    RevocationMode = System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509RevocationMode.NoCheck
                };   #endif
```

Answer (score 0):

To help with troubleshooting, you can add this temporarily to log additional info about the cert that's causing the validation failure. I logged it to NLog's txt log but you can create EventLog if you want:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) =>
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.AppendLine($"  Certificate Subject: {certificate.Subject}");
    sb.AppendLine($"  Certificate Issuer: {certificate.Issuer}");
    sb.AppendLine($"  Certificate CertHash: {certificate.GetCertHashString()}");
    sb.AppendLine($"  Certificate EffectiveDate: {certificate.GetEffectiveDateString()}");
    sb.AppendLine($"  Certificate ExpirationDate: {certificate.GetExpirationDateString()}");
    sb.AppendLine($"  sslPolicyErrors: {sslPolicyErrors.ToString()}");
    sb.AppendLine($"  ChainPolicy:");
    sb.AppendLine($"     Chain revocation flag: {chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationFlag}");
    sb.AppendLine($"     Chain revocation mode: {chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode}");
    sb.AppendLine($"     Chain verification flag: {chain.ChainPolicy.VerificationFlags}");
    sb.AppendLine($"     Chain verification time: {chain.ChainPolicy.VerificationTime}");
    sb.AppendLine($"     Chain status length: {chain.ChainStatus.Length}");
    sb.AppendLine($"     Chain application policy count: {chain.ChainPolicy.ApplicationPolicy.Count}");
    sb.AppendLine($"     Chain certificate policy count: {chain.ChainPolicy.CertificatePolicy.Count}");

    sb.AppendLine($"  ChainStatus:");
    foreach (var cs in chain.ChainStatus)
    {
        sb.AppendLine($"     Chain certificate policy count: Status: {cs.Status}, StatusInformation: {cs.StatusInformation}");
    }

    NLog.Common.InternalLogger.Error($"ServerCertificateValidationCallback: {sb}\n");

    return true;
};
```

Answer (score -6):

Add this to your client code :

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(
    delegate
    {
        return true;
    });
```

Comment: This answer isn't very good, as it does not explain the risks associated with the code.