# What does this C# code with an "arrow" (=>, an equal sign and greater than sign) mean and how is it called?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I was trying to enable SSL in my C# client program and found the following code [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1742938/wcf-could-not-establish-trust-relationship-for-the-ssl-tls-secure-channel-with/1742967#1742967):

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
    (se, cert, chain, sslerror) =>
    {
        return true;
    };
```

I added the code to my program and it solved the problem, but I completely don't get how exactly it works.

The left part `System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback` is some callback and `+=` modifies that callback. But what does the remaining construct mean? I spent 20 minutes searching to at least find how it is properly called and where I can find more info on how to read that, but all in vain. I suppose it is somehow related to LINQ and searched for "LINQ arrow", but didn't find anything reasonable.

How is that `(blah,blah,blah)=>{return true;}` construct called and where can I find more info on such constructs?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

That is a [lambda expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions). It is a very special anonymous [delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/reference-types#the-delegate-type). Basically you are defining a method and not giving a name. Its parameters are to the left of the `=>` and the method body is to the right of the `=>`. In your particular case,

```
(se, cert, chain, sslerror) => { return true; };
```

is an anonymous method defined by a lambda expression. This particular method has four parameters

```
object se
X509Certificate cert
X509Chain chain
SslPolicyErrors sslerror
```

and the method body is

```
return true;
```

It's as if you had said

```
class ServerCertificateValidation {
    public bool OnRemoteCertificateValidation(
        object se,
        X509Certificate cert,
        X509Chain chain,
        SslPolicyErrors sslerror
    ) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

and then

```
var validation = new ServerCertificateValidation();
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
    validation.OnRemoteCertificateValidation;
```

> How is that `(blah,blah,blah)=>{return true;}` construct called and where can I find more info on such constructs?

It's called the same way that any other method is called. For example, you can do this:

```
Func<int, int, int> adder = (m, n) => m + n;
```

Here I am defining a method that eats a pair of `int` and returns an `int`. That `int` is obtained by adding the values of the input parameters. It can be invoked like any other method.

```
int four = adder(2, 2);
```

Here's an article on MSDN on [lambda expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) and an article on the [lambda operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311046.aspx). If you're really interested, the name comes from [lambda calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus).

Comment: Besides of the syntax I want to know is this sort of implementation (returning true value for all cases) does not lead to a security bug? I mean we should do some validation and this sort of returning true for all cases makes our code prone to security-risks.

Comment: It seems this sort of implementation is a security risk and this case is noted in the answer of main question [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1742967/1080355)

Comment: I like reading your messages in SO @jason thanks

Comment: What about the question marks in this line of code? `public IRepository<Guia> GuiaRepository => _guiaRepository ?? (_guiaRepository = new Repository<Guia>(_context));` I mean, the `??`.

Comment: Please do not WRITE codes encoding methods or functions like that. It is unreadable and hard to maintain later. :)

Answer (score 24):

For completeness (for search results, etc): in more recent versions of C# (since 6.0), the `=>` syntax has been extended from just lambdas for delegates and expression trees, to cover [expression-bodied members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members). This means that a range of simple members such as properties, methods, etc - can be implemented as expression bodies; for example:

```
public int Foo { get { return innerObj.SomeProp; } }
public void Bar() { Write("Thing"); }
```

can be written:

```
public int Foo => innerObj.SomeProp;
public void Bar() => Write("Thing");
```

Answer (score 12):

The [`=>`-Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-operator) represents a lambda expression.

But for those of you who visit the question nowadays, another use-case might be the arrow as a shorthand for a property getter. This feature got introduced in C# 6. So instead of writing

```
public string Foo
{
    get
    {
        return this.bar;
    }
}
```

you can use following snippet:

```
public string Foo 
{
    get => this.bar;
}
```

or even shorter:

```
public string Foo => this.bar;
```

Comment: This is a usecase that got supported long after the question was asked.

Comment: It is unreadable and hard to maintain.

Comment: @TomeeNS I totally agree. The long version with alle the brackets is totally unreadable and hard to maintain.

Answer (score 6):

It's called a [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311046.aspx - The lambda operator.

Answer (score 4):

```
(blah,blah,blah)=>{return true;}
```

is a lambda expression.  It doesn't look like the lambdas you're used to because it doesn't use any arguments which get passed to it.  The compiler will turn this lambda into a delegate function for you, without you having to go through the long, annoying process of creating a whole function which implements the delegate specification that ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback uses.

Answer (score 4):

Jason explains it very well.  Here is an example using an event that is listened to using different techniques:

```
using System;

namespace Events
{
   class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Events e = new Events();
            e.FireEvents();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class Events
    {
        private event EventHandler<EventArgs> EventTest;

        public Events()
        {
            EventTest += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(function);

            EventTest += delegate
            {
                Console.WriteLine("written by an anonymous method.");
            };

            EventTest += (o, e) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("written by a lambda expression");
            };
        }

        private void function(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("written by a function.");
        }

        public void FireEvents()
        {
            if (EventTest != null)
                EventTest(this, new EventArgs()); 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This snippet is called anonymous function. It builds an anonymous method around the callback delegate and allways returns true.