# IIS: self-signed certificate for external web api

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api, https

My company has external web api service and I want to make it secure using SSL certificate. This service is called by internal application only. Is it secure to use self-signed certiifcate in IIS on production?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is secure to use a self-signed certificate even.though it is not best practice for Production environment.

Indeed the Root CA will be unknown and the client cannot validate the issuer. Your client will have to accept such a certificate (this means you will have to handle the certification check yourself)

[How to ignore the certificate check when ssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506575/how-to-ignore-the-certificate-check-when-ssl)

If the API is used only internally, it is not a big deal. If you have some external consumers, you should really just go and buy a certificate.