# Why is the server forcibly closing the connection? What does it expect from the client?

Tags: c#, compact-framework, windows-ce, servicepoint, servicepointmanager

In trying to call a REST method on a server app running on our local network from my app running on a handheld device, it fails with "*Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS ...System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host*" .

In more recent / full-featured versions of .NET, you can add this code to the client:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
```

...as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506575/how-to-ignore-the-certificate-check-when-ssl) to accept the server's response. This is not available for me in my Windows CE / Compact Framework app, though - although ServicePointManager is a "known quantity," ServerCertificateValidationCallback is not. This is part of the Windows.NET assembly, [apparently](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.servercertificatevalidationcallback(v=vs.90).aspx), which is not available to me in this project.

So, assuming there is still a way to accomplish the same thing (accept the ssl-ified server's response), how can this be done in this scenario?

One proposed workaround was to add a class to my client like this:

```
namespace HHS
{
    using System.Net;
    using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

    class TrustAllCertificatesPolicy : ICertificatePolicy
    {
        public TrustAllCertificatesPolicy()
        {
        }

        public bool CheckValidationResult(ServicePoint sp, X509Certificate cert, WebRequest req, 
int problem)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

...and then call this on app startup (such as in the main form's Load() event):

```
private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.CertificatePolicy = new TrustAllCertificatesPolicy();
}
```

...but I still get this exception in my log file:

```
Message: From FileXferREST.SendHTTPRequestNoCredentials(): Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS; Inner Ex: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.ReceiveNoCheck(Byte[] buffer, Int32 index, Int32 request, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Connection.System.Net.ISslDataTransport.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.SslConnectionState.ClientSideHandshake()
   at System.Net.SslConnectionState.PerformClientHandShake()
   at System.Net.Connection.connect(Object ignored)
   at System.Threading.ThreadPool.WorkItem.doWork(Object o)
   at System.Threading.Timer.ring()
; Stack Trace:    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.finishGetRequestStream()
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
   at HHS.FileXferREST.SendHTTPRequestNoCredentials(String uri, HttpMethods method, String data, String contentType)
. . .
```

BTW, TrustAllCertificatesPolicy's (empty) constructor is probably moot, as it is grayed out.

What is it, exactly, that the server is expecting from the client? Why is the server forcibly closing the connection?

### UPDATE

On trying to determine if it's a problem in my client code or server code, I tried to hit the URL via Postman, but get this:

[image]

So, I followed the "importing SSL certificates in Chrome" link to see if that might help.

That [http://blog.getpostman.com/index.php/2014/01/28/using-self-signed-certificates-with-postman/] tells me:

Turns out that there is a better solution to solve this a problem, and it also avoids adding an exception to Chrome every time you start the browser. This is how you do it:

```
1. Go to the root URL in your browser. For ex. https://localhost
2. Click on the lock icon on the top left in the URL bar.
. . .
```

However, on entering `https://localhost` in Chrome, I get "This webpage is not available"

Trying `http://localhost` instead ("http" instead of "https"), OTOH, I get an "IIS7" image, with "welcome" in a slew of (human) langauges.

The, as to step 2 ("Click on the lock icon on the top left in the URL bar."), I see no such thing there; this is what I see:

[image]

So am I doomed?

Comment: You might have to explicitly set the protocol (e.g. ` ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls`)

Comment: Thanks, but I get, "Cannot resolve SecurityProtocol" and "Cannot resolve SecurityProtocolType".

Comment: Hmm, maybe it's a CF 1.0/3.5 difference.  I haven't used anything but 3.5 for years.

Comment: This is 3.5 (the "next gen" version of our current 1.0 release)

Comment: If a browser can't get to it, then your app can't either.  Get it working from a browser first.

Comment: My app can get to it, but then the server forcibly closes it.