# Ignoring SSL Errors with Flurl in Xamarin

Tags: ssl-certificate, dotnet-httpclient, flurl

I would like to have Flurl and the underlying HttpClient library ignore SSL errors so I can dev locally.

Specifically, I have a web api that requires a SSL certificate.  I create a temporary one so I can dev locally, however Flurl and HttpClient return an error on the SSL check.

How can I disable the SSL error check?

Comment: You can't "disable" a server-side check from the client. Are you just trying to get SSL to work in your dev environment? This has been asked and answered many times, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506575/how-to-ignore-the-certificate-check-when-ssl) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22251689/make-https-call-using-httpclient). If that's not what you're looking for then I think some more details are needed. Please post the relevant code and exception details.

Comment: @Todd Menier Yes, I'm just trying to get SSL working in my dev environment.  Essentially, I want to do this: `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };`  And I'm wondering if there's an easy way to do that with flurl?

Comment: Flurl doesn't provide any sort of shortcut for that, but adding that line should have the exact same effect on a Flurl call as it does on an HttpClient call.

Comment: Ok, so it turns out this was working all along.  The problem was, I had a HockeyApp component in my project that was overwriting these settings.  Disabling HockeyApp did the trick!

Comment: Never trust a hockey player. Glad you got it figured out.