# WSE + self-signed certificat

Tags: c#, ssl, self-signed, wse

There is an old code on the WSE (Web Services Enhancements). Now in "sandbox" of service with which it works for HTTPS began to use self-signed certificat.
And now in the sandbox i am getting error -- Could not create SSL / TLS secure channel.
Something like this does not help.

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
                (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
```

How i can to ignore a certificate?

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to do something like this to ignore cert validation.

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
```

you could also see this question and answers for additional details that might better apply to your situation.

[How to ignore the certificate check when ssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506575/how-to-ignore-the-certificate-check-when-ssl)