# iis express development certificate is not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio, rest, ssl-certificate

I am using rest-api (I built the server as ASP.NET and the client as explained here:  https://www.codeprojeAt.com/Tips/497123/How-to-make-REST-requests-with-Csharp)
And I want to use ssl during my development. For some reason when I use the "iis express development certificate" I still get this error:
System.Net.WebException: 'The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.'
AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

Any ideas..?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a self-signed development certificate, a typical web client will not be able to validate it, because it was not created by a certificate authority that maps back to a root authority. You have two choices:

1. In your web client, [disable validation of the chain of trust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506575/how-to-ignore-the-certificate-check-when-ssl).
2. Install the self-signed cert as a root cert on the machine running the web client. Not all certs can be installed this way, so you may actually have to generate a development root cert, use it to generate your site's development cert, then install the development root cert.

Comment: Can you please be more specific in option 2?

Comment: Read [this blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/robert_mcmurray/2013/11/15/how-to-trust-the-iis-express-self-signed-certificate/), which contains step by step instructions and screen shots.