# How to make gRPC client comunicate with a gRPC server in a different machine? Both in Aspnet Core 3.0. Possible SSL problem

Tags: ssl, grpc, asp.net-core-3.1

So, by the title you know what I'm trying to build.

I already have one gRPC server and 3 clients talking together in the same machine. The server is accessible on http://localhot:5001. Everything runs smoothly but if I run the clients on another machine they cannot access the server. So I installed IIS and placed the server there for it to get served to outside with the domain beta.server.com. I altered the hosts file on the client machine to go to the computer ip(192.168.5.49) where the server is running on IIS.

When I try to access with the browser by http i get a message saying i can only connect with a gRPC client. By https says NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID. Maybe this is the problem...(found out after writing the rest).

By trying to connect with a gRPC client to http(http://beta.server.com) I get an error saying http/1.1 is not supported, which is true, this service works only on http2.

When try to connect to the server ip with https(https://beta.server.com) I get the error that the ssl connection could not be established. As follows:

```
PS C:\Users\Farm\Desktop\GrpcSierConsole\Viewer> dotnet run
Entered task
Unhandled exception. System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Status(StatusCode=Internal, Detail="Error starting gRPC call: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception."))
 ---> Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode=Internal, Detail="Error starting gRPC call: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.")
   at Grpc.Net.Client.Internal.HttpContentClientStreamReader`2.MoveNextCore(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Grpc.Core.AsyncStreamReaderExtensions.ReadAllAsync[T](IAsyncStreamReader`1 streamReader, CancellationToken cancellationToken)+MoveNext()
   at Grpc.Core.AsyncStreamReaderExtensions.ReadAllAsync[T](IAsyncStreamReader`1 streamReader, CancellationToken cancellationToken)+System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource<System.Boolean>.GetResult()
   at Viewer.Program.<>c.<<Main>b__0_0>d.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Farm\Desktop\GrpcSierConsole\viewer\Program.cs:line 24
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Viewer.Program.<>c.<<Main>b__0_0>d.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Farm\Desktop\GrpcSierConsole\viewer\Program.cs:line 24
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
   at Viewer.Program.Main() in C:\Users\Farm\Desktop\GrpcSierConsole\viewer\Program.cs:line 29
```

The error is on line 29 on the program.cs in the server. The code I have there is the following:
Line 29 is webBuilder.UseStartup():

```
//Additional configuration is required to successfully run gRPC on macOS.
        // For instructions on how to configure Kestrel and gRPC clients on macOS, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2099682
        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
```

I've tried to use the Visual Studio localhost certificate and a self signed certificate within the IIS in both the client computer and the server computer running IIS.

Also I've used this line in the client to trust all certificates:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
```

Which I got from: [How to ignore the certificate check when ssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506575/how-to-ignore-the-certificate-check-when-ssl)

I don't know what more to do. Anyone can help?

#####################    UPDATE     ######################

I've added this code to the client

```
var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
// Return `true` to allow certificates that are untrusted/invalid
httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = 
    HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator;
var httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);

var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://localhost:5001",
    new GrpcChannelOptions { HttpClient = httpClient });
 var client = new QueueManagement.QueueManagementClient(channel);
...
```

Now I don't have the SSL error but this one:

```
PS C:\Users\Farm\Desktop\GrpcSierConsole\Viewer> dotnet run
Entered task
Unhandled exception. System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Status(StatusCode=Internal, Detail="Error starting gRPC call: An error occurred while sending the request."))
 ---> Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode=Internal, Detail="Error starting gRPC call: An error occurred while sending the request.")
   at Grpc.Net.Client.Internal.HttpContentClientStreamReader`2.MoveNextCore(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Grpc.Core.AsyncStreamReaderExtensions.ReadAllAsync[T](IAsyncStreamReader`1 streamReader, CancellationToken cancellationToken)+MoveNext()
   at Grpc.Core.AsyncStreamReaderExtensions.ReadAllAsync[T](IAsyncStreamReader`1 streamReader, CancellationToken cancellationToken)+System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource<System.Boolean>.GetResult()
   at Viewer.Program.<>c.<<Main>b__0_0>d.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Farm\Desktop\GrpcSierConsole\Viewer\Program.cs:line 32
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Viewer.Program.<>c.<<Main>b__0_0>d.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Farm\Desktop\GrpcSierConsole\Viewer\Program.cs:line 32
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
   at Viewer.Program.Main() in C:\Users\Farm\Desktop\GrpcSierConsole\Viewer\Program.cs:line 37
```

And at line 37 i have the task.wait() because this runs inside a task.

```
var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://beta.server.com",
    new GrpcChannelOptions { HttpClient = httpClient });
                var client = new QueueManagement.QueueManagementClient(channel);

                var request = client.QueueNumberChanged(new SendQueueId { QueueId = "2" });
                await foreach (var response in request.ResponseStream.ReadAllAsync())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Senha {response.Number} -> fila 2");
                }
            });
            t.Wait();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a great research and many messages exchanged in Issues at Microsoft official GitHub Repository for .Net Core kestrel documentation i found it.

It can be done with this settings on appsettings.json

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Kestrel": {
    "EndpointDefaults": {
      "Protocols": "Http2"
    },
    "EndPoints": {
      "Https": {
        "Url": "https://*:5002",
        "Certificate": {
          "Path": "c:\\test.pfx",
          "Password": "password1234"
        }
      }
    }
  },
}
```

Comment: What if it is not hosted in Kestrel? I need it to work from Xamarin app. Any solution?