# AngleSharp returns strange response

Tags: anglesharp

I run the code that was working a couple of months ago.  But now the code return only the following:

```
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
```

The code:

```
                var requester = new DefaultHttpRequester("Chrome/76.0");
                requester.SupportsProtocol(ProtocolNames.Https);

                var config = Configuration.Default
                    .WithDefaultLoader(loaderOptions)
                    .With(imageLoaderService)
                    .With(_cookieProvider)
                    .With(requester);

                var browsingContext = BrowsingContext.New(config);
```

All other sites I tried return the full html as usual...

What can be the reason?

Comment: I tried with and without: requester, loaderOptions, imageLoaderService, _cookieProvide etc.

Comment: I suspect it has nothing to do with the page - its rather the server. It may be an HTTPs issue.

Comment: Keep in mind that .NET is not your browser so pages that have a valid certificate in your browser may be invalid in .NET. That's just how it is. Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506575/how-to-ignore-the-certificate-check-when-ssl to check if disabling verification helps.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue.  Code similar to that in the original question ran fine this morning then in the evening started returning <html><head></head><body></body></html> with StatusCode = OK.  When I use a standard C# WebRequest to the same address from the same computer I get the full html.  How can I debug this?