# Win32Exception: The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted. httpClient mTLS .NET7.0 configuration

Tags: c#, .net, https, client, mtls

I am experiencing an issue with temporary skipping SSL validation. Below is the code used for testing communication:

```
static void Main()
{
    var stringToSend = "Hello World!";
    var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
    handler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;
    var clientCertPKandChain = new X509Certificate2("client-cert.pfx");

    handler.ClientCertificates.Add(clientCertPKandChain);
    handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) =>
    {
        var certErrors = errors;
        if (certErrors != SslPolicyErrors.None)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    };
    try
    {
        HttpContent content = new StringContent(stringToSend.ToString());
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
        HttpResponseMessage response1 = httpClient.PostAsync("somehost", content).Result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       
    }
}
```

As you can see, I attempted to skip server certificate verification. Although the verification is successful, the following exception is thrown:

Win32Exception: The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.

I have tried various solutions, including the one mentioned in this link:
[How to ignore the certificate check when ssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506575/how-to-ignore-the-certificate-check-when-ssl).

When I use OpenSSL on Linux, it works fine, and the handshake is performed with my client-cert.crt.
This application works on .NET7.0 but I've tried also on .NETFramework 4.7.2 and .NET6.0 and .NET5.0. Also in Rider on Linux system without success

Comment: You cannot ignore this error.  A certificate must be issued by an valid authority so hackers cannot get access to your data.  Because it is working on other systems it seems like the certificate is ok and the authority is ok.  Most likely older versions of Net do not support the encryption mode in the certificate and that is why you are failing.  The error you are getting may not be accurate.   Are you always running code on same machine?  Starting with Net 4.7.1 TLS is performed in the OS, not in Net.  This sound like a OS issue and not Net/Core.

Comment: Can you dive into the chain you get also in the callback? Presumably one of the certs in the chain is the problem and when you compare the elements of the chain with the status of those elements you might find a problematic intermediate cert or a missing intermediate cert on that machine.

Comment: `if (certErrors != SslPolicyErrors.None) { return false;` is telling it to fail if there are certificate chain errors. Side note: `handler`, `content` `httpClient` and `response` need `using` to dispose them. Do NOT use `.Result` on a `Task`, instead `await` it.