# 'MANAGE PRIVATE KEYS' option missing

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-security, x509certificate

I'm developing WCF service with Transport Security hosted on IIS 7.5 under Windows 2008R2. I have a certificate, generated in IIS 7.5 which is stored in Local folder.

When I use BasicHttpBinding or WSHttpBinding with Transport Security - everything works fine. But when I change it to NetTcp I get an exception :

```
 CryptographicException 'Keyset does not exist'.
```

After a bit of googling I found out that the problem can be because my NETSERVICE IIS account doesn't have premission to the private key of my certificate.

The solution could be to set the rights to accesss in MMC by right-clicking on my certificate and selecting "MANAGE PRIVATE KEYS" option. But there is no such option in the select menu!!! The Certificate was created under administrator account and where I open it - it says, that it has private key. What I'm I doing wrong?

Comment: hope this helps: http://forums.asp.net/t/1832898.aspx

Comment: Thanks, but same result (((

Comment: Give the account rights to the file that has the private key.  Don't remember off-hand where that exists, but it's findable.

Comment: How to find this file? In Windows server 2003 (http://geekswithblogs.net/technetbytes/archive/2011/10/12/147281.aspx) it is quite easy, but in Windows server 2008 I cant find its location? Maybe you know where it is?

Comment: seems to not work when connecting to a remote server's certificate store even when running as admin and logging in with admin credentials. In addition if you select 'export' then the 'export private key' is grayed out :-(

Answer (score 27):

Go to server -> click Start -> Run -> type mmc -> enter -> select Certificates snap-in with Local Computer option -> Go to Console Root-> Certificates-> Personal-> Certificates-> Select a cert-> Right click-> Go to All tasks-> Manage Private Keys-> Add permissions

Comment: Just adding -> For 'Manage Private Keys' you should import .pfx file not .cer

Answer (score 19):

In Windows 10 1809, it seems that the **Manage Private Keys** option is available only to certificates in the Personal store. The workaround is to drag and drop the certificate there, add permissions as needed and drag it back to where you need it.

Answer (score 12):

Manage Private Keys option was missing when I first tried adding the certificates. Finally corrected it by following two steps.

1. Ran MMC as an administrator. File-> Add or remove Snap-ins-> Select Certificates -> Click on Add button.This will open a dialog. This snap-in will always manage certificate for : choose Computer account. Select the computer you want this snap-in to manage : choose Local computer. Click Finish. Click ok.
2. When you import the certificates(All tasks -> Import) in the Personal Folder, Make sure you are importing the .pfx file and NOT the .cer file.

Comment: I'll second this, had the same problem, was served a .cer file and not .pfx from the customer :)

Answer (score 10):

I had this same problem (Manage Private Keys option missing). In order to get it to appear I had to add the Certificates snap-in using the "Computer account" option instead of the default "My user account"

Answer (score 3):

#### The Manage Private Keys Option is only available for certificates with an exportable private key

In my case, I experienced this problem despite configuring the Certificates snap-in to access the COMPUTER account. Further, the suggestion to get a .PFX certificate in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37867991/2227908) isn't an option for me.

I solved the problem by specifying that the private key be exportable when creating the certificate request (which I'm doing via the Certificates MMC snap-in):

[image]

Even though the certificate I got back from the public CA was a `.CER` file, the Manage Private Keys menu option was available for it. I don't know a lot about certificates, but I conclude that the menu option only appears when the private key can be exported.  In light of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37867991/2227908), perhaps certificates in the .PFX format *always* allow this to be done. Nonetheless, it's good to know it's possible for other certificate formats.

Answer (score 1):

There can be one other problem, so I will mention it. Except `-pe` argument when creating a certificate using makecert.exe, be sure you are importing the `.pfx` file, not the `.cer`. If there is not a `.pfx` file, use an additional tool such as `pvk2pfx.exe` to created.

Answer (score -1):

1. Open the Command Prompt (Run as Administrator)
2. Enter and execute command, 
   **certutil** -repairstore my "thumbprint" (replace thumbprint
   with the 32 characters)
3. If succesful, you will recieve message,
   **certUtil**: -repairstore command completed successfully.