# How to install or use a certificate without a request

Tags: ssl, mmc, sha2

We receive a SHA-2 certificate from a vendor to use on our site when making requests to them.  This is unlike anything i have done before.  Typically in IIS we would create the request, receive the certs and install.

In this scenario we were just handed one for requests to them.  Anyone know how or what is supposed to be done with them?

Did use MMC and installed the cert that way, but not sure how or if that is to link to website.

Comment: What kind of code do you use to make a request to the vendor?

Comment: It's a SOAP request.

Answer (score 0):

It's only for server side certificates that you use the IIS management console.  It sounds like this is a client certificate used to identify your app to someone else.

It is up to the language you are using to call the webservice to determine where the certificate should be placed.  If you are using C# then there [are lots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17090511/wcf-and-client-certificate-authentication?rq=1) of questions that talk about using client certificates.  I would imagine that most languages would let you reference the certificate file directly.