# How do I bypass this error 'Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel'?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, ssl

I'm getting this error while creating a token on some remote web service:
Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority 'wvcert.bfc-usa.com'

I was looking it up, and found some links. [link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1742938/wcf-could-not-establish-trust-relationship-for-the-ssl-tls-secure-channel-with)

[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1742938/wcf-could-not-establish-trust-relationship-for-the-ssl-tls-secure-channel-with): [WCF : Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19670190/wcf-could-not-establish-trust-relationship-for-the-ssl-tls-secure-channel-with) and [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1742938/wcf-could-not-establish-trust-relationship-for-the-ssl-tls-secure-channel-with). I cannot browse that website on my server's browser, so cannot really see what's going on. I checked the Trusted certificates authority on my server's browser settings, but I can see that the Root certificate is added as a trusted there. 
So now I'm trying to add the code from link 2 into my client. Where do I add this code? I'm not sure where this code will go in my client

Comment: Troubleshoot it via System.NET tracing, or WCF tracing, or simply SSL handshake analysis by capturing the packets on the wire. You do have a lot of ways to dive into it.