# How do I resolve "Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel" with IIS Express

Tags: wcf, visual-studio, iis

I have a WCF service throwing an exception, "Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel".

When launching the service, IIS Express prompts to trust the IIS Express SSL Certificate and I select Yes. When accessing the endpoint from IE10, the address bar turns red indicating a certificate error. When I run my code and hit the endpoint, the exception is thrown.

How do I resolve this in IIS Express?

Using Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 and IIS Express.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WCF: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1742938/wcf-could-not-establish-trust-relationship-for-the-ssl-tls-secure-channel-with)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The certificate is probably only in Personal store (CurrentUser\My or LocalMachine\My) and it certainly is selfsigned. Check if the certificate is in Trusted Root store using mmc. If not copy it there (probably in LocalMachine\Trusted Root so that all users will trust this certificate).

Comment: Thanx you saved my day!

Comment: @Raphael I'm glad :)