# BasicHTTPBinding and Trust Relationship

Tags: wcf, security, ssl

I am attempting to connect to a web service. The certificate for this service is located on the server. I am creating the service like so:

```
BasicHttpBinding basicbinding = new BasicHttpBinding();

// Transport needed for HTTPS according to msft
basicbinding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;

endPoint = new Client(basicbinding, new EndpointAddress(myURL);
```

When I try to get data from the service (`endPoint.getSomeData(...)` I get an exception:

```
Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority..."
```

**Question**: Do I need to also specify:

```
basicbinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
```

And if so, do I need to have the cert on my end too?

**Update**: The server doesn't authenticate using client certificates. So I guess all I need to do is set `basicbinding.Securtiy.Mode` to `BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport` and set `basicbinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None`?

Comment: Is the server certificate trusted by the client? Or signed by a certificate that is trusted by the client?

Comment: I don't know the answers to those questions. I do not have access to the cert. I only know that is was created from a trusted authority.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WCF : Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority - back to the drawing board](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1742938/wcf-could-not-establish-trust-relationship-for-the-ssl-tls-secure-channel-with)

Comment: Just got a little more info:

Comment: I just got some more info: The server doesn't authenticate using client certificates. So I guess all I need to do is set basicbinding.Securtiy.Mode to BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport and set basicbinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None ?