# Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority after communication

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, tls1.2

Recently one of our clients installed a new certificate on their server. I installed the certificates including Root certificates on my server. Since then I’m getting the following error.

“Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority”

The error is suddenly thrown between the minute 0 and 10 while continually requesting and posting to the web service. I’v created a consale app writing the method and soap header to the console to see if everything is going good. Then suddenly the error is thrown.
If there was something wrong with the certificate I should not even be able to call the first method “getsoapheader”. Any idears how this error rises and why.
I have already tried the following.

- Accept all certificates in code using ref: [How to solve "Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1742938/how-to-solve-could-not-establish-trust-relationship-for-the-ssl-tls-secure-chan)
- Installed certificates in local, personal and trusted CA folders in mmc

I also mailed the application to our client for testing. They unfortunately could not find an error. The application run perfectly every time. I can’t get it to work once om my PC using the exact same code.

Any help would be highly appreceated.

```
(1) Start webservice test
(x) Exit
```

1
28-6-2016 14:18:18 SoapHeader: bf2c890a-18c1-4fe0-8197-9da2bd37f0c0
28-6-2016 14:18:18: GetConstructorCLWorkOrderList date: 1
28-6-2016 14:18:18: GetConstructorCLWorkOrderList date: 1
28-6-2016 14:18:18: GetConstructorCLWorkOrderList date: 2
28-6-2016 14:18:19: GetConstructorCLWorkOrderList date: 3
28-6-2016 14:18:19: GetConstructorCLWorkOrderList date: 4
28-6-2016 14:18:19: GetConstructorCLWorkOrderList date: 5
28-6-2016 14:18:19: GetConstructorCLWorkOrderList date: 6
28-6-2016 14:18:19: GetConstructorCLWorkOrderList date: 7
28-6-2016 14:18:19: GetConstructorCLWorkOrderList date: 8
28-6-2016 14:18:20: GetConstructorCLWorkOrderList date: 9
28-6-2016 14:18:20: GetConstructorCLWorkOrderList date: 10
28-6-2016 14:18:20: GetConstructorCLWorkOrderList date: 11
28-6-2016 14:18:20: GetConstructorCLWorkOrderList date: 12
28-6-2016 14:18:20: GetConstructorCLWorkOrderList date: 13
28-6-2016 14:18:20: GetConstructorCLWorkOrderList date: 14
28-6-2016 14:18:20: GetConstructorCLWorkOrderList date: 15
28-6-2016 14:18:21: GetConstructorCLWorkOrderList date: 16
28-6-2016 14:18:21: GetConstructorCLWorkOrderList date: 17
28-6-2016 14:18:21: GetConstructorCLWorkOrderList date: 18
28-6-2016 14:18:21: GetConstructorCLWorkOrderList date: 19
28-6-2016 14:18:21: GetConstructorCLWorkOrderList date: 20
28-6-2016 14:18:21: GetConstructorCLWorkOrderList date: 21
28-6-2016 14:18:21: GetConstructorCLWorkOrderList date: 22
28-6-2016 14:18:21: GetConstructorCLWorkOrderList date: 23
28-6-2016 14:18:22: GetConstructorCLWorkOrderList date: 24
28-6-2016 14:18:22: GetConstructorCLWorkOrderList date: 25
28-6-2016 14:18:22: GetConstructorCLWorkOrderList date: 26
28-6-2016 14:18:22: GetConstructorCLWorkOrderList date: 27
28-6-2016 14:18:22: GetConstructorCLWorkOrderList date: 28
28-6-2016 14:18:22: GetConstructorCLWorkOrderList date: 29
28-6-2016 14:18:22: GetConstructorCLWorkOrderList date: 30
28-6-2016 14:18:22: GetConstructorCLWorkOrderList date: 31
28-6-2016 14:18:23: GetConstructorCLWorkOrderList date: 32
28-6-2016 14:18:23: GetConstructorCLWorkOrderList date: 33
28-6-2016 14:18:23: GetConstructorCLWorkOrderList date: 34
28-6-2016 14:18:23: GetConstructorCLWorkOrderList date: 35
28-6-2016 14:18:23: GetConstructorCLWorkOrderList date: 36
28-6-2016 14:18:23: GetConstructorCLWorkOrderList date: 37
28-6-2016 14:18:23: GetConstructorCLWorkOrderList date: 38
28-6-2016 14:18:24: GetConstructorCLWorkOrderList date: 39
28-6-2016 14:18:24: GetConstructorCLWorkOrderList date: 40
28-6-2016 14:18:24: GetConstructorCLWorkOrderList date: 41
28-6-2016 14:18:24: GetConstructorCLWorkOrderList date: 42
28-6-2016 14:18:24: GetConstructorCLWorkOrderList date: 43
28-6-2016 14:18:24: GetConstructorCLWorkOrderList date: 44
28-6-2016 14:18:24: GetConstructorCLWorkOrderList date: 45
28-6-2016 14:18:25: GetConstructorCLWorkOrderList date: 46
28-6-2016 14:18:25: GetConstructorCLWorkOrderList date: 47
28-6-2016 14:18:25: GetConstructorCLWorkOrderList date: 48
28-6-2016 14:18:25: GetConstructorCLWorkOrderList date: 49
28-6-2016 14:18:25: GetConstructorCLWorkOrderList date: 50
28-6-2016 14:18:25: GetConstructorCLWorkOrderList date: 51
28-6-2016 14:18:25: GetConstructorCLWorkOrderList date: 52
28-6-2016 14:18:25 GetWorkOrder start
28-6-2016 14:18:30 GetWorkOrder: 104159
28-6-2016 14:18:30 SoapHeader: c033f8da-1b4a-45f3-a160-7727b8086123
28-6-2016 14:18:30 GetWorkOrder start
28-6-2016 14:18:34 GetWorkOrder: 99055
28-6-2016 14:18:35 SoapHeader: 8eea7e21-23bd-4cf5-8d56-28606f8527b2
28-6-2016 14:18:35 GetWorkOrder start
28-6-2016 14:18:38 GetWorkOrder: 109876
28-6-2016 14:18:39 SoapHeader: 7df630db-c8e5-4bd6-9558-ea05cf541e4b
28-6-2016 14:18:39 GetWorkOrder start
28-6-2016 14:18:44 GetWorkOrder: 101382
Kan geen veilig kanaal tot stand brengen voor SSL/TLS met autoriteit acceptatie-webservice-xx.xxx.com.
-2146233087
De aanvraag is afgebroken: Kan geen beveiligd SSL/TLS-kanaal maken.

Server stack trace:
   bij System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
   bij System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   bij System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   bij System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   bij System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   bij System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   bij System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]:
   bij System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   bij System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   bij Webservicetest.Gemma.GemmaWebService.Authenticate(String username, String password)
   bij Webservicetest.Gemma.GemmaWebServiceClient.Authenticate(String username, String password) in C:\Webservicetest\Webservicetest\Service References\Gemma\Reference.cs:regel 14444
   bij Webservicetest.Program.GetSoapHeader() in C:\Webservicetest\Webservicetest\Program.cs:regel 78
   bij Webservicetest.Program.Validate() in C:\Webservicetest\Webservicetest\Program.cs:regel 131
   bij Webservicetest.Program.StartWebserviceTest() in C:\Webservicetest\Webservicetest\Program.cs:regel 62

(1) Start webservice test
(x) Exit

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the biggest headache right now. The awnser is a Microsoft update that was installed on my laptop the same day as the client installed there new certificate. Making me search in the wrong place for the error. If you get this error please remove the following update.

Security update for Microsoft Windows (KB3163017)

After removing this update everything worked fine again.