# Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel- when adding or consuming new WCF Web services reference in VS2019

Tags: asp.net-core, web-services, ssl, wcf-binding

I need to add WCF service reference in .NET core 5.0 project on VS2019 When doing this I am getting the below error:

> An error occurred while attempting to find services at 'https://ws-xxxxxx/xxxrtnerConnection?wsdl'. The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

I have also tried below ways for solving this issue but no luck:

1. Installed SSL certificate in in my local machine.
2. Then I can access the service in browser.
3. I saved/download that service in machine after that able to consume saved service using `Add service reference` from vs2019.
4. When trying to access contained method inside service then getting below error:

> Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority 'ws-xxxxxx/xxxrtnerConnection'.

But the amazing thing is that everything is working fine when I am consuming service in MVC project after consuming it adds `customBinding` xml code in web.config file and there is no such file in .Net core project.

So what should I do for consuming service in .NET core project.

Comment: .NET 5 is no longer supported. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/microsoft-net-and-net-core) for more information.

Comment: You can try to add a ServerCertificateValidationCallback that handles the ServicePointManager program on the client side (not a good method, but you can see if the error message disappears).`System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
    (se, cert, chain, sslerror) =>
        {
            return true;
        };` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1742938/how-to-solve-could-not-establish-trust-relationship-for-the-ssl-tls-secure-chan

Comment: The following may be helpful: [Configuring WCF Services in Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/configuring-wcf-services-in-code),  [WCF Alternatives for .NET 5](https://visualrecode.com/blog/wcf-alternatives-for-net5/), [gRPC for Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) developers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/why-migrate-wcf-to-dotnet-grpc?view=aspnetcore-6.0), and [https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/corewcf-v1-released/](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/corewcf-v1-released/).