# One or more errors occurred. (Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL /TLS secure channel

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using third party url in my dot net core webapi but when i am calling this url it showing me below error:

One or more errors occurred. (Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL
/TLS secure channel with authority 'api.example.com'.)

Below is my code how i am calling it

```
using (ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient()) {
            client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = ACCOUNT;
            client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = PASSWORD;
            
            using (OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel)) {
                HttpRequestMessageProperty httpRequestProperty = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
                
                
                httpRequestProperty.Headers[System.Net.HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ACCOUNT + ":" + PASSWORD));
                OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] = httpRequestProperty;
                
                try

                {
                    
                    ret = func(client);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ret = new ApiErrorResponse(ex);
                }
            }
```

I have tried below but it not helped.

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
    (se, cert, chain, sslerror) =>
        {
            return true;
        };
```

Comment: Are you trying to run this behind any corporate firewall ?

Comment: No. Only global firewall without restriction outgoings connections

Comment: try this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1742938/how-to-solve-could-not-establish-trust-relationship-for-the-ssl-tls-secure-chan

Comment: Do you get a certificate error when trying to open the API URL in edge or chrome?

Comment: In my dotnet core api i am using external api to get data from external source. When i am hitting api.exampleurl.com using client credentials i am getting this error

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below code:

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) => true;

using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
{
    ....
    .....
}
```

Comment: actually i am trying to calling webservices in dotnet core api example https://api.example.com but this giving me error. I have installed the certificate for this webservice but not working

Comment: @vikassaini it would be great if you can run some tool like network monitor or Wireshark to troubleshoot the issue. that might give you more information. and share the logs snapshot by excluding the private information.

Comment: also try accessing the url in the browser  and click on the certificate and get the details so that it can help to understand what is the actual issue

Comment: Actually in browser it’s working well without any issue. But not in my api

Comment: could you capture the network as suggested @vikassaini

Comment: Thank you @Jalpa. Issue is resolved after updated windows server to 2022

Comment: @vikassaini which os you were using before?

Comment: Windows server 2012 r2

Comment: @vikassaini could you try adding this code in your app and try running it in on 2012r2 again `ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls
       | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11
       | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
       | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;`

Comment: i tried all but these not worked for me