# WCF Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority

Tags: wcf, ssl, azure, self-signed

**Scenario:**

I've a WCF web service called SERVICEA hosted in Azure. It's uses self signed certificate for HTTPS. 
This SERVICEA inspect the incoming request and determines whether to call:

> 1. SERVICEB OR
> 2. SERVICEC

Both SERVICEB AND SERVICEC also uses self signed cert. for https.

**PROBLEM:**

When I deploy the SERVICEA and try to call so that it invokes SERVICEB I get the error message below:

*

> Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel
>   with authority "SERVICEB..."

*.

Note it says SERVICEB.. on error message.

Anyidea how I can resolve this issue, please?

Comment: could anyone please help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Could not establish trust relationship for SSL/TLS secure channel -- SOAP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/703272/could-not-establish-trust-relationship-for-ssl-tls-secure-channel-soap)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to validate the server certificate if its self signed as shown below:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, error) => true;
```

Comment: Thanks @Rajesh I tried that but still did not work. Same error.

Comment: @flybyte: where did you write that piece of code. That code should be in the client side i.e. inside ServiceA that calls ServiceB as ServiceA is the client for ServiceB

Comment: -1: Your solution disables certification validation, which is not ideal if the application handles more than the one self signed certificate.

Comment: @reSPAWNed Can you please elaborate on what you mean by application handles more than one self signed certificate? Also the question was on how to get it working when using self signed certificates.

Comment: @Rajesh: Your event handler always returns true, instead of inspecting the sender, certificate, chain or error parameters. This means that all certificates now appear to be valid, even if that was not the purpose. If the application accesses multiple SSL sites, then all of their certificates appear to be valid, instead of just the ones with self signed certificates. Take a look at my answer, where I have supplied a more elaborate solution.

Comment: @reSPAWNed: The above code is written in the client application and the developer should know what applications he is accessing and should also be aware that in Live environments self signed certificates are not to be used. It is upto the developer to know the security implications when writing any code

Comment: @Rajesh: I agree that we as programmers have a responsibility to always consider security implications when writing code. But this site is where the less experienced can ask for guidance and in that respect, I also feel that is the responsibility of the more experienced people to supply the best possible solution to a problem. And in live environments there is nothing wrong with self signed certificates, as long as they come from a source you trust.

Answer (score 0):

You want to trap the ServerCertificateValidationCallback and make it ignore certificates of your choosing.
Here is a decent article that explains how: http://blog.jameshiggs.com/2008/05/01/c-how-to-accept-an-invalid-ssl-certificate-programmatically/

Comment: Hi @Igorek,thank you. Our webservice is consumed by third party vendor who uses PHP and Java. How would they achive the same? And is it security risk to ingore certificate?  Or should I install Server Certificate by RDP to Azure Server?

Comment: I do not know much about PHP and Java, but they would need to code a line similar to the one provided to ignore self-signed certificates.  This is indeed a security risk.  To do it right, would be to purchase a valid SSL cert and upload it to your Azure service.

Comment: Thank you @Igorek, I first tried Rajesh's solution which looked short and worked. I will definitely bookmark your link. Thank you for your help, much appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Rajesh is onto something, but his answer disables certification checks altogether.

Instead I would suggest an event handler like the following should be added to your application:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=  (sender, certificate, chain, errors) =>
{
    var request = sender as HttpWebRequest;
    if (request != null && request.Address.Host == "<Your domain name goes here>")
        return true;

    return errors == SslPolicyErrors.None;
};
```