# File Backup/Sync between two servers

Tags: wcf, file-upload, https, backup, windows-server-2008-r2

We're using windows 2008 R2 servers and we need to backup the file to the other server whenever a file gets uploaded.

Unfortunately, the client requires that there would be no file/directory sharing between servers via LAN so we are trying to do this via WCF calling another WCF. But now we're having problem calling the other WCF since they're hosted on SSL-secured website.

Calling the WCF via silverlight works.

Questions:

1) What might be causing the SSL/TLS error when the WCF calls the other but everything works fine  for the silverlight calling the WCF?

code:

```
public FileUpload(FileUploadClass file)
{
    // store locally
    ...

    // call the other wcf
    if (!fileIsExisting)
    {
       ServiceRefClient svcClient = new ServiceRefClient();
       svcClient.FileUploadClass(file)
    }
}
```

2) Any other way to backup the file to the other server securely apart from using WCF and Database (I'm trying database now but hopefully there is a prettier way to do this)? File/Directory/Drive sharing via local network is prohibited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since dealing with security issues are often tough and time consuming, I decided to store the file as binaries to the database and load it from the 2nd server instead.

Impersonation works but that's really more of bypassing the securities.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give more details on the exact error? Meanwhile you may want to check:

- Assuming Server B hosting the WCF File Backup service is using a self signed certificate, does server A which is calling Server B have the certificate imported in the appropiate certificate store?
- Again an assumption: Check Server A´s application pool identity, does it have sufficient permissions to call Server B?

Comment: Error is something like "cannot establish ssl/tls relationship...". 2nd item: it's not a problem because wcf a accesses server a and same is true to wcf b. i also stored the certificates on trusted root certs store.

Comment: Check the following thread, there are a couple of different ideas given how to diagnose the problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/703272/could-not-establish-trust-relationship-for-ssl-tls-secure-channel-soap