# Fiddler not intercepting PowerShell web requests

Tags: powershell, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to use Fiddler to help someone troubleshoot an issue with `Invoke-RestMethod` calls to an ASP.NET WebAPI. Unfortunately, when I call `Invoke-RestMethod` in PowerShell, Fiddler is not intercepting the HTTP communications.

When I use Internet Explorer to browse the root of the ASP.NET website, which is part of the same application, Fiddler intercepts traffic as expected.

Can anyone explain why Fiddler is not capturing HTTP traffic through PowerShell, and how to resolve this?

Comment: I'm surprised you're not using Message Analyzer :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Fiddler actually works via a proxy, and automatically sets proxy settings in IE when running. You can check this by launching fiddler and then checking "Lan Settings" under Internet Options > Connection.

`Invoke-RestMethod` has a `-Proxy` parameter you can use to point to Fiddler's proxy. I think the default is 127.0.0.1:8888 :

`Invoke-RestMethod -Proxy 'http://127.0.0.1:8888' ....`

**Edit**: Adding screenshot to confirm the answer above.

[image: Fiddler Options]

Comment: Hmmmm, while your answer is accurate, it seems that it's not capturing when I specify the `-Proxy` parameter. Were you able to test it successfully?

Comment: Nope I did not test since I don't have a simple test case for Invoke-RestMethod right now :)

Comment: Yes, this works:


`Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'http://blogs.msdn.com/powershell/rss.aspx' -Proxy 'http://127.0.0.1:8888'`

Comment: Edited, looks like the format of the Proxy matters!

Comment: Hmmmmm, still having trouble on my end ... investigating.

Comment: So, your example with the MSDN Blogs RSS feed works, but it's not capturing stuff locally ...

Comment: Not sure what you mean locally...we can chat if you like.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57931/discussion-between-trevor-sullivan-and-jnk).

Comment: Any conclusion on this? I'm seeing a similar issue that I use the prescribed method on a Windows 8.1 box and do not see any results in Fiddler.

Comment: @KentFehribach maybe it's version dependent (for fiddler versions)? It works fine for me in Win 8.1

Comment: @JNK The issue is specifically when calling to LocalHost, calling to any remote machines works as expected.

Comment: @JNK having a similar issue. Added -Proxy to the request. This does seem to proxy through fiddler but does not display the request. Any suggestions?

Comment: I had filters set up which I needed to disable!

Comment: Rather than using `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`, use the actual local IP address like `192.168.1.25`

Comment: This doesn't work when I use `Invoke-WebRequest` - also tried IP address instead of localhost.

Comment: this will not intercept powershell requests. I want to catch the docker pull url's but unable to do that with fiddler. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue (with Powershell & Fiddler2 ) while installing NPM packages.

It worked [after setting up Fiddler as a Reverse Proxy](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/UseFiddlerAsReverseProxy) then using the command mentioned in the answer here (thanks for that JNK).

**Step-by-step instructions below:**

1. Follow the steps mentioned [here](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/UseFiddlerAsReverseProxy) and write the one line FiddlerScript Rule to use Fiddler as a Reverse Proxy.

In my case it was:

> if (oSession.host.toLowerCase() == "127.0.0.1:8888") oSession.host = "127.0.0.1:80";

[image]

2. Then in PowerShell use the configured proxy settings:

> PS F:> npm install yo -g **-proxy 'http://127.0.0.1:8888'**

3. Now the PowerShell traffic should flow through Fiddler.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work by resetting the fiddler https certs (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22478741/2063755)).

> I had the same problem while I was testing a project and it turned that running Fiddler was the cause for this error..!!
>
> If you are using Fiddler to intercept the http request, shut it down ...
>
> This is one of the many causes for such error.
>
> To fix Fiddler you may need to [Reset Fiddler Https Certificates](http://textslashplain.com/2015/10/30/reset-fiddlers-https-certificates/).

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the posted solutions in powershell v5 , but it is not working.

The only solution is using `powershll core v7.x (tried v7.4)` and it works fine
and Fiddler CAN intercep PowerShell web requests.

Also, using curl.exe from within powershel v5 with proxy option is working:

```
curl.exe ...  -x 127.0.0.1:8888
```