# The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure with self-signed certificate

Tags: c#, vb.net, ssl, translation, self-signed

I'm getting the error `The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure when requesting an URL on my local development machine.

I already looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9983265/the-remote-certificate-is-invalid-according-to-the-validation-procedure).

But I can't find the VB.NET code for this C# code:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (o, c, ch, er) => true;
```

OR

```
// Put this somewhere that is only once - like an initialization method
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateCertificate);
...

static bool ValidateCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors errors)
{
   return true;
}
```

Can someone help me with the translation of this code? I tried the translators converter.telerik.com and carlosag.net but those fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than just translate let's first determine what this line does

```
 ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (o, c, ch, er) => true;
```

The MSDN docs says that [ServerCertificateValidationCallback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager.servercertificatevalidationcallback?view=net-5.0#code-snippet-1) is a property of type [RemoteCertificateValidationCallback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.security.remotecertificatevalidationcallback?view=net-5.0)

RemoteCertificateValidationCallback is a delegate with this signature

```
'Declaration
Public Delegate Function RemoteCertificateValidationCallback ( _
    sender As Object, _
    certificate As X509Certificate, _
    chain As X509Chain, _
    sslPolicyErrors As SslPolicyErrors _
) As Boolean
```

This `(o, c, ch, er) => true;` is a lamba expression with the signature RemoteCertificateValidationCallback and always evaluates true.

To do the same in VB.NET it's

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = Function(o,c,ch,er) (true)
```

[This article will help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/delegates/) will you with the second part, but it's the same idea.