# TFS server 2015: Email alerts not working

Tags: email, azure-devops, tfs-2015

TFS email alerts is not working for some reason. Any possible reasons ?

I think tfs 2015(VSO) doesn't need SMTP server settings  and should directly work.  I created simple requests, none are working. what's possibly can go wrong  ?

[simple alert request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqP9k.jpg)

more info: TFS server running on  windows 2008 server

Comment: Talk to your operations team and ensure that the alerts aren't getting bounced by your SMTP server.

Comment: thanks for the reply. but why you gave -1 ?

Comment: ...Which one are you actually using TFS2015 or VSTS(Changed name from VSO)? TFS2015 is on-premise and VSTS is could side.

Comment: For TFS2015 the server address should be `http://xxx:8080/tfs` and For VSTS(VSO) the server address should be `https://youraccoutn.visualstudio.com`

Comment: Thanks Patrick,   i am using TFS2015.  But i still can see "my alerts" in my profile menu.    https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/track/alerts-and-notifications , it  was mentioned -  If you don't see this option, then you must configure an SMTP server to support TFS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using on-premise TFS server2015.

For feedback requests and alerts to work, you still need to **configure an SMTP server** for TFS.

> Details steps from MSDN: [Configure an SMTP server to support alerts
>   and feedback requests](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms400808.aspx)

Give a try after you finish the configuration to see if it works.

---

***My setting***

[image]

Comment: I tried configuring "Alert  settings"  .looks fine. But when sending the Test email, i got the error   : "Remote certification is invalid according to the validation procedure. "  , any help , please ?

Comment: This issue seems related to SMTP server. Are you using correct SMTP server address? Please also take a look at *Anders Abel*'s answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9983265/the-remote-certificate-is-invalid-according-to-the-validation-procedure.

Comment: Did you check the `This server requires a secured connection(SSL)` ? If so, give a try with uncheck it. Also update my setting for your reference.

Comment: Thanks again. I am using the correct server.  i also tried unchecking SSL. then i got SMTserver requires Secure conncetion or client was not authenticated.  i will try Anders Abel's answer.

Comment: No SSL and Authentication: not required. then its working.  Thanks a lot for help !!!