# Linux docker: System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure

Tags: linux, docker, ssl, .net-core, ssl-certificate

The following code (.Net core 2.1) runs fine in Visual Studio in Windows.

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback <- fun _ _ _ _ -> true
use request = new HttpRequestMessage(RequestUri = uri, Method = httpMethod)
use client = new HttpClient(handler)
let! response = client.SendAsync(request) |> Async.AwaitTask
```

However, it got the following error when running in a Linux container. It seems a certificate issue according to the question of [The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9983265/the-remote-certificate-is-invalid-according-to-the-validation-procedure). Is it a way to find and install the certificate of the particular website and installed it in the docker container?

`$ docker run crawlers:latest gmac 201808
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.) ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, ExceptionDispatchInfo exception)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.PartialFrameCallback(AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ThrowIfExceptional()
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndAuthenticateAsClient(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<>c.b__47_1(IAsyncResult iar)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func2 endFunction, Action1 endAction, Task1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask1.get_Result()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask1.get_Result()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.WaitForCreatedConnectionAsync(ValueTask1 creationTask)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask1.get_Result()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.DecompressionHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, ExceptionDispatchInfo exception)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.PartialFrameCallback(AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ThrowIfExceptional()
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndAuthenticateAsClient(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<>c.<AuthenticateAsClientAsync>b__47_1(IAsyncResult iar)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func2 endFunction, Action1 endAction, Task1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask1.get_Result()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask1.get_Result()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.WaitForCreatedConnectionAsync(ValueTask1 creationTask)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask1.get_Result()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.DecompressionHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)<---
[15:08:36 FTL] Login exception.
System.Exception: One or more errors occurred. (The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.) (The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.)`