# Docker CE for Windows - SSL connection could not be established. remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure

Tags: docker, ssl

I am having an SSL issue when calling internal https url (like https://sample/demoapi/api/item/) from a containerized .net core 2.2 API. The API works fine when run outside of container.

Note: The container works perfect when mounting the ssl folder from the Docker thin Linux VM to the container.
docker run -itd -p 5011:80 -v /etc/ssl/certs:/etc/ssl/certs

Information
Windows Version: Win 10
Docker for windows CE Version: Docker CE 2.0.0.3 (not the latest. I have DNS name resolution issue when calling a URL from a container with the latest docker CE. Docker 2.0.0.3 is the one found working without issues)
Docker is running on windows 10 machine not on VM. Running Linux host and containers.
I have followed the following resolutions to copy and update the ssl certificate onto the container but didn't work.
[Linux docker: System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52261388/linux-docker-system-security-authentication-authenticationexception-the-remote?rq=1)
[How do I add a CA root certificate inside a docker image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42292444/how-do-i-add-a-ca-root-certificate-inside-a-docker-image)

Steps to reproduce the issue:

1. Create a sample .net core api and call an https service as follows.

   try
       {
         var client = new HttpClient();
         var resp = await client.GetAsync("https://test.com");
         data = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
       }
       catch(Exception e)
       {
          data = e.StackTrace + "- " + e.Message + " - " + e.InnerException;
       }
2. Publish the application as specified above
   Application type: .net core 2.2 api
   Publish configuration:
   Target framework: .netcoreapp2.2
   Deployment method: self-contained
   Target run time: linux-x64
3. Build image using the docker file
   FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2 AS runtime
   COPY Publish/ app/
   COPY ./certf.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/certf.crt
   RUN chmod 644 /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/certf.crt && update-ca-certificates
   ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "app/testapp1.dll"]
4. Run docker command - docker run -itd -p 5011:80 --name demoapi demoapi
5. Browse the url http://localhost:5011/api/vales/ and see the error

Error received:
at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask1.get_Result() at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask1.get_Result()
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.WaitForCreatedConnectionAsync(ValueTask1 creationTask) at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask1.get_Result()
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts) at demoapiapp1.Controllers.ValuesController.Get(Int32 id) in C:\dev\Controllers\ItemsController.cs:line 41 ----- The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. <--------------------> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure. at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, ExceptionDispatchInfo exception) at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at System.Net.Security.SslState.PartialFrameCallback(AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Net.Security.SslState.ThrowIfExceptional() at System.Net.Security.SslState.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult) at System.Net.Security.SslState.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult result) at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndAuthenticateAsClient(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<>c.b__47_1(IAsyncResult iar) at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func2 endFunction, Action1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Answer (score 3):

Found the problem and resolved it. Posting this to help anyone who experience the same problem.

I used wrong certificate. The certificate to be used is the certificate authority certificate (root certificate) but I used the certificate issued to the system. I generated the root certificate from the chain and imported to container using the 'stakoverlow' resolution referenced above.

Resolution: The ca certificate is named as ca-cert.crt.
Added the following lines the Dockerfile.

```
COPY ca-cert.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/ca-cert.crt
RUN chmod 644 /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/ca-cert.crt && update-ca-certificates
```

Comment: You must add this certificate to your container's