# Office 365 Mail App cross domain iframe

Tags: office365, outlook-addin

I want to launch a popup from the mail app I am making that contains an iframe to a different domain.  The iframe launches a site with flash that doesn't get loaded.  If I launch the site directly everything runs as expected.  Any assistance is appreciated.

Also, I am hosting the mail app locally using a nodejs app.  I also am wondering if because the app is hosted locally if that could be causing issues as well.  I self signed the app to allow for https and that all seems to be working appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because of the self-signed app. I ran into a similar problem before. 
I had to bypass the certificate validation thanks to this line of code.

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ((sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true);
```

I found it here by the way
[self signed cert. The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11266674/self-signed-cert-the-underlying-connection-was-closed-could-not-establish-trus)

Comment: Will that work in a nodejs app (javascript)??  Also, with more tinkering we found that our hosted app was sandboxed in the add-in pane which isn't allowing my flash to load.